# MySQL, better to insert NULL or empty string?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-null

I have a form on a website which has a lot of different fields. Some of the fields are optional while some are mandatory. In my DB I have a table which holds all these values, is it better practice to insert a NULL value or an empty string into the DB columns where the user didn't put any data?

Answer (score 226, accepted):

By using `NULL` you can distinguish between "put no data" and "put empty data".

Some more differences:

- A `LENGTH` of `NULL` is `NULL`, a `LENGTH` of an empty string is `0`.
- `NULL`s are sorted before the empty strings.
- `COUNT(message)` will count empty strings but not `NULL`s
- You can search for an empty string using a bound variable but not for a `NULL`. This query:

  ```
  SELECT  *
  FROM    mytable 
  WHERE   mytext = ?
  ```

  will never match a `NULL` in `mytext`, whatever value you pass from the client. To match `NULL`s, you'll have to use other query:

  ```
  SELECT  *
  FROM    mytable 
  WHERE   mytext IS NULL
  ```

Comment: but which one you think is faster? 0 or NULL or ""

Comment: in InnoDB NULL's take up less space

Comment: I think this is an okay answer, but it also totally ignores the "best practice" element of the question and only focuses on tangentially relevant facts (NULL sort order and length? These don't matter). On most text data input types there **is not** a difference between "no response" and "empty response", so I think this is a great question that deserves a better answer.

Comment: NULLs also work great when UNIQUE field is set. For example if you have a field like Driving License to add person’s DL No. and the guy doesn’t have it. Since it’s a unique field the first person with no DL No. will get added but not the next as it will throw an error of unique constraint. So, NULL is better.

Comment: @SaifurRahmanMohsin: it's a textbook example of bad practice to set driving license number as unique.

Comment: I just came up with it as an example. You can replace it with anything that requires unique. Like say IMEI code of mobile equipment or google place ID for places.

Comment: @Quassnoi why that?

Comment: @cedbeu: why what?

Comment: @Quassnoi ah sorry... I meant, why is it a bad practice to set driving number licence as unique...?

Comment: @cedbeu: because it's not unique. And even if it is unique today, tomorrow your legislation body can make it not unique.

Comment: There is a performance surplus to using NULL.
If you have to add an extra WHERE clause to skip '' empty elements, of course it is slower.

Answer (score 46):

One thing to consider, if you **ever** plan on switching databases, is that [Oracle does not support empty strings](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/empty_null.php).  They are converted to NULL automatically and you can't query for them using clauses like `WHERE somefield = ''` .

Comment: This sounded incredibly fishy to me, even on your link, so I tried it. Null field, set to '', oracle ignores it. Reports length as null rather than 0. That's just so wrong. There's got to be some way around this. Think I'll post this as another question.

Comment: `Steve B.`: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171196/difference-between-varchar-and-varchar2

Comment: Thanks for the reference, though I still don't understand the reasoning.

Posted as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268177/oracle-not-distinguishing-between-nulls-and-empty-strings

Comment: Might be worth updating the answer to include info from the link posted by Quassnoi

Comment: @Steve B: that was a design decision made by Oracle a _l_o_n_g_ time ago. They can't change that behavior without breaking a whole boatload of legacy Oracle applications that are designed around this behavior.  So, Oracle is forever stuck with this design decision (that zero length strings are equivalent to NULL.)

Comment: Peoplesoft (with Oracle DB) uses a single space to indicate an empty value.  Incredibly stupid.  They also use 0.00025 to indicate 0 for FTE since 0 is not allowed. Lovely choices were made in that product.

Answer (score 10):

One thing to keep in mind is that NULL might make your codepaths much more difficult. In Python for example most database adapters / ORMs map `NULL` to `None`.

So things like:

```
print "Hello, %(title)s %(firstname) %(lastname)!" % databaserow
```

might result in "Hello, None Joe Doe!" To avoid it you need something like this code:

```
if databaserow.title:
    print "Hello, %(title)s %(firstname) %(lastname)!" % databaserow
else:
    print "Hello, %(firstname) %(lastname)!" % databaserow
```

Which can make things much more complex.

Comment: In my opinion abusing your database to "fix" errors in your code or the framework is a (very) bad coding practice. When there is no data you should just insert NULL and be consistent in using that. Otherwise you must use statements like: if(myString == null || myString = ""). When an object is not set or defined in your code you are also using NULL instead of some kind of "placeholder" (which an empty string is in my opinion).

Comment: Depends very much on your Language of choice. In Python "if not myString:" tests for None and "". Probably mainly a cultural issues. The Java Guys "bad practice" is the dynamic person's elegance.

Answer (score 10):

Better to Insert `NULL` for consistency in your database in MySQL. Foreign keys can be stored as `NULL` but NOT as empty strings.

You will have issues with an *empty string* in the constraints. 
You may have to insert a fake record with a *unique empty string* to satisfy a Foreign Key constraint. Bad practice I guess.

See also: [Can a foreign key be NULL and/or duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573590/can-a-foreign-key-be-null-and-or-duplicate)

Comment: The constraints issue has tripped me up in the past so that is why I "+1" this answer.

Comment: But if you use NULL make very sure you never end up with any empty strings as well.  Easy to do with many UI technologies.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know what best practice would be here, but I would generally err in favor of the null unless you want null to mean something different from empty-string, and the user's input matches your empty-string definition.

Note that I'm saying YOU need to define how you want them to be different. Sometimes it makes sense to have them different, sometimes it doesn't. If not, just pick one and stick with it. Like I said, I tend to favor the NULL most of the time.

Oh, and bear in mind that if the column is null, the record is less likely to appear in practically any query that selects (has a where clause, in SQL terms) based off of that column, unless the selection is for a null column of course.

Comment: ...And now that I see the answer above me, I think it's safe to say that the usual differentiation you would care about is no data versus empty data. :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using multiple columns in a unique index and at least one of these columns are mandatory (i.e. a required form field), if you set the other columns in the index to NULL you may end up with duplicated rows. That's because NULL values are ignored in unique columns. In this case, use empty strings in the other columns of the unique index to avoid duplicated rows.

```
COLUMNS IN A UNIQUE INDEX:
(event_type_id, event_title, date, location, url)

EXAMPLE 1:
(1, 'BBQ', '2018-07-27', null, null)
(1, 'BBQ', '2018-07-27', null, null) // allowed and duplicated.

EXAMPLE 2:
(1, 'BBQ', '2018-07-27', '', '')
(1, 'BBQ', '2018-07-27', '', '') // NOT allowed as it's duplicated.
```

Here are some codes:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `event_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `event_title` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `location` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `event_id` (`event_id`,`event_title`,`date`,`location`,`url`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Now insert this to see it will allow the duplicated rows:

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `event_id`, `event_title`, `date`, `location`, 
`url`) VALUES (NULL, '1', 'BBQ', '2018-07-27', NULL, NULL);

INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `event_id`, `event_title`, `date`, `location`, 
`url`) VALUES (NULL, '1', 'BBQ', '2018-07-27', NULL, NULL);
```

Now insert this and check that it's not allowed:

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `event_id`, `event_title`, `date`, `location`, 
`url`) VALUES (NULL, '1', 'BBQ', '2018-07-28', '', '');

INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `event_id`, `event_title`, `date`, `location`, 
`url`) VALUES (NULL, '1', 'BBQ', '2018-07-28', '', '');
```

So, there is no right or wrong here. It's up to you decide what works best with your business rules.