# Is it possible to store '' (empty string) as a non NULL value in the database?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am using Oracle DB. At the database level, when you set a column value to either NULL or '' (empty string), the fetched value is NULL in both cases. Is it possible to store '' (empty string) as a non NULL value in the database?

I execute this

```
UPDATE contacts SET last_name = '' WHERE id = '1001';

commit;

SELECT last_name, ID FROM contacts WHERE id ='1001';

LAST_NAME                  ID
------------               ------
null                       1001
```

Is it possible to store the last_name as a non-NULL empty string ('')?

Comment: Of course the correct thing to do would be to store unknown values as null not empty string.

Comment: An Empty string is a valid value. It is not an unknown value. A null tells us that user does not know the last_name of this contact so we have to get the last_name from LDAP if possible. An empty string tells us that the user has deliberately deleted the last_name of this contact so it is not an unknown value. It has a defined value of an empty string which is different from null which stands for an unknown value.

Comment: Well aware of Oracle's historical problem with equating '' with NULL, and kind of agree, but if the only reason you want to store '' is to tell that a user has deleted a value, then that's why you have log or journal tables. In other words, avoid designs that call for magic values that have special meanings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way to do this in oracle is with some kind of auxiliary flag field, that when set is supposed to represent the fact that the value should be an empty string.

Answer (score 4):

Oracle has a well know behavior that it silently converts `""` to `NULL` on INSERT and UPDATE statements.

You have to deal with this in your code to prevent this behavior by converting `NULL` to `""` when you read the columns back in and just do not use `null` in your program to begin with.

Comment: How can I "deal with this in my code to prevent this behavior"?

Comment: Of course you can easily convert `NULL` to `''`, `'sproing'`, or anything else.  But the problem is that you can't distinguish between a value and not a value.

Comment: this is why `null` was called the *Billion Dollar Mistake*, and that was when a billion dollars was a lot of money, today it is the *Trillion Dollar Mistake*.

Comment: Was `null` a mistake, or just the way it was implemented?  I agree there are a number of dumb inconsistencies with `null` in SQL.  However, if `null` didn't exist, we would have a lot of extra flag columns for whether values were set, or a lot of special handling of values like `-999`.  Not a good situation either.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson, what does NULL in SQL have to do with pointers?

Answer (score 4):

As far as i know Oracle does not distinguish between '' and NULL, see [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268177/oracle-not-distinguishing-between-nulls-and-empty-strings)

Answer (score 1):

A long time since I used Oracle, but I believe we used to use a single space ' ' to represent an empty string, then trim it after reading.

Comment: until someone needs to store a single space in the string... you'd need some kind of escape sequence or something, then you'd have to make sure all the code that works with that column knows how to interpret the special syntax :(

Comment: "until someone needs to store a single space in the string" - yes of course, this only works if, for example, trailing whitespace is not significant.  Which is true in many applications.

Comment: A data access layer can deliberately prefix absolutely every string with one character when running on Oracle (stripping it back off on retrieval). It's ugly as hell. But then “ugly as hell” and Oracle go well together.

Comment: I recall a select query in which where clause relied on the presence of an empty space i.e. ' ' We accidently trimmed the bind variable and voila there were over a million records that were being returned to the client because somewhere in the million lines of code, there was a logic to remove the where clause if the variable was empty. Needless to say, we had a severe loss of service. Of course, we could put a max limit on the resultset and dozen other good things that we learnt as a result of the accident.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp, a lot of default database behavior (such as string comparison) ignores trailing spaces, so if you need to store a single space in a field and treat it differently than an empty string, you probably need to do something special anyway.

Comment: @dan1111 you shouldn't have any trouble with functions ignoring trailing spaces, if you avoid CHAR and stick to the standard VARCHAR2 data type.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `VARCHAR2` data type then `NULL` and `''` are identical and you cannot distinguish between them; so, as mentioned in other answers, you would either need to:

- Have an additional column that contains a flag that distinguishes between non-`NULL` and `NULL` values so that if then flag states it is non-`NULL` and it contains a `NULL` then you know it is an empty string; or
- Use an alternate representation, such as a single space character, for an empty string. This would then mean that you cannot store a string with that alternate representation; however, if trailing white-space was syntactically invalid for the strings you are storing then using a single space character to represent an empty string would be fine.

---

If you are using a `CLOB` data type then you **CAN** store an empty string using the `EMPTY_CLOB()` function:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value CLOB);

INSERT INTO table_name (value) VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO table_name (value) VALUES (EMPTY_CLOB());
INSERT INTO table_name (value) VALUES ('A');
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT value, LENGTH(value) FROM table_name;
```

Outputs:

> | VALUE | LENGTH(VALUE) |
> | --- | --- |
> | *null* | *null* |
> |  | 0 |
> | A | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=03c173bec5db07f2169780b8a0d63083)*