# How to return empty string in resultset (using sys_refcursor) in ORACLE DB

Tags: c++, oracle, occi

After facing the problem:

> ORA-32108: max column or parameter size not specified

I researched a little and I found these two questions: [Why does Oracle 9i treat an empty string as NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203493/why-does-oracle-9i-treat-an-empty-string-as-null) and [Oracle not distinguishing between nulls and empty strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268177/oracle-not-distinguishing-between-nulls-and-empty-strings) .

---

These questions explain the error I get. But this led me to the next question - how can I return empty string as a field value in a ResultSet in Oracle?

---

What I have so far is:

- create the statement
- register output parameter as `oracle::occi::OCCICURSOR`
- `execute` the statement
- the I call `GetCursor` to use the returned resultset

The `execute` fails, because of the error, described above.

So, how can I return such field in the resultset, which has value an empty string (`''`)?

In other words, I don't know how to apply the action, specified [HERE](http://ora-32108.ora-code.com/) - is it something server-side? Or I should add something in my code? Or in the stored procedure, that returns this resultset?

---

I use OCCI (Oracle C++ Call Interface). My current workaround is to return a string, containing a single space (`' '`), but I don't like it.

Comment: This means you want a completely null column returned? You could see if cast will work, `cast( null as varchar2(1))`.

Comment: Ah, this cast works like a charm! Thanks! Can you add it as an answer?

Comment: I'm glad! I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a completely NULL column returned you can use [`CAST()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions023.htm#SQLRF00613), which converts one data type into another.

For instance the following would generate a completely null column.

```
select a.*, cast(null as varchar2(1)) as null_column
  from my_table a
```

But, the database now understands that this should be a column of VARCHAR2(1), whereas if you use `null as null_column` there has been no maximum length specified.