# Select fields not equal to the empty string in oracle

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to write a query that simply selects all non-empty names. Both the following queries return no results:

```
 SELECT name FROM MyTable WHERE name != '';

 SELECT name FROM MyTable WHERE name = '';
```

For context, both of these queries do return results:

```
 SELECT name FROM MyTable WHERE name != 'a';

 SELECT name FROM MyTable WHERE name IS NOT NULL;
```

I read somewhere that the empty string is equivalent to NULL in oracle, but I still don't see why that explains this behaviour.  I need to support both SQL Server and Oracle which is why I can't just rely on `WHERE name IS NOT NULL`

Can anyone explain what's happening here?  Thanks!

Comment: Hi friend, this depends a bit on the type of your column. Oracle behaves a bit unexpectedly on varchar2 vs char columns. This other question has details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268177/oracle-not-distinguishing-between-nulls-and-empty-strings?rq=1

Comment: I don't know your app and support and how you do it, but this might be a task for and ORM?  It would be interesting to see if it helped.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Oracle 9i treat an empty string as NULL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203493/why-does-oracle-9i-treat-an-empty-string-as-null)

Comment: To support both SQL Server and Oracle why don't you use (name!='' or name is not null)? Provided that each condition supports one database.

Comment: @user2672165 has it correct, although I would probably reverse the order to where (name is not null or name <> '')

Comment: I don't think that'll work, I need (name <> '' and name is not null) for SQL Server but just (name is not null) for Oracle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any comparison that involves a NULL value will always return FALSE.

Comment: I think that explains it, thanks. I also found this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements005.htm which says "Because null represents a lack of data, a null cannot be equal or unequal to any value or to another null" which explains why name is neither equal nor not-equal to null.

Comment: Any comparison that involves NULL returns UNKNOWN, not FALSE. However, a SELECT statement only returns a record when the WHERE clause is TRUE, which neither FALSE nor UNKNOWN is.

Answer (score 4):

> Can anyone explain what's happening here? Thanks!

From the [Ask Tom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:5984520277372) archive.

A ZERO length varchar is treated as NULL.

'' is not treated as NULL.

'' when assigned to a char(1) becomes ' ' (char types are blank padded strings).

'' when assigned to a varchar2(1) becomes '' which is a zero length string and a zero 
length string is NULL in Oracle (it is no longer '')

Comment: @mason Essentially when you insert a zero length string into a Varchar2 column, it becomes a NULL in Oracle.  This goes against what the ANSI standard reads, but Oracle has been doing their own thing forever.

Comment: So is `''` a zero length string?

Comment: @mason Yes, if there are no characters between the quotes, then it is a zero length string

Comment: **But** you said in your answer that `''` is not treated as NULL, but that zero length strings are NULL. Which is it?

Comment: @mason Was a cut/paste job from the Article, there are no zero length strings in Oracle varchars. You can do a quick test of that with: DECLARE
A VARCHAR(2);
BEGIN
A := '';

IF A = '' THEN 
  dbms_output.put_line('Empty String');
ELSE 
  dbms_output.put_line('It''s NULL');
END IF;

IF '' = '' THEN 
  dbms_output.put_line('Empty String');
ELSE 
  dbms_output.put_line('It''s NULL');
END IF;

END;