# Is it good to use a default of NULL?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, null, phpmyadmin

I have some columns that may contain data that is if the user wants to provide it.

Example | **Email** | **First Name** | **Last Name** |

Email - Required so column is set to NOT NULL - Default: None

First Name - Not Required so column set to NULL - Default: NULL

Last Name - Not Required so column set to NULL - Default: NULL

In phpmyadmin when creating/editing a column; it has an option saying **Default:** with a drop down showing **None | As Defined | NULL | Current Timestamp**

Because **First Name | Last Name** is optional and not required should I choose default NULL or maybe NONE?

Which is best and why please?

I know there are many discussions on this already but I could not find any that answered my question; they was more in regards to allowing NULL or NOT NULL, my question is about default value.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should set them to Default:Null as if the user doesn't provide any info for that fields, they should be null obviously.

Answer (score 7):

Use NULL, None mode is inserting 'None' or some '' string to indicate that there is nothing there....

For more information why you want to use NULL versus a string look here:  [MySQL, better to insert NULL or empty string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267999/mysql-better-to-insert-null-or-empty-string)

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to index those NULL columns, you'll really get performance problems on big tables (with more than 1 million rows...). However, using an empty string or NULL as a string ('null') for a default value may increase your query performance on those cases. BTW, I'm not telling that NULL is evil, but those are some cases we've faced in telco business.

Comment: Thanks for the head up on that. I won't be indexing those columns with NULL values in so that should hopefully not be a problem for me. Thanks phplover