# Can a foreign key be NULL and/or duplicate?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, foreign-keys

Please clarify two things for me:

1. Can a Foreign key be NULL?
2. Can a Foreign key be duplicate?

As fair as I know, `NULL` shouldn't be used in foreign keys, but in some application of mine I'm able to input `NULL` in both Oracle and SQL Server, and I don't know why.

Comment: From the horse's mouth: _“Foreign keys allow key values that are all NULL, even if there are no matching PRIMARY or UNIQUE keys”_ https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_constraints.htm#sthref549

Comment: this cannot be deleted because the answers and the question are useful. Feel free to edit the question to improve it.

Comment: partial duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366854/can-table-columns-with-a-foreign-key-be-null

Answer (score 725, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, it can be NULL or duplicate.

I want to explain why a foreign key might need to be null or might need to be unique or not unique. First remember a Foreign key simply requires that the value in that field must exist first in a different table (the parent table). That is all an FK is by definition. Null by definition is not a value. Null means that we do not yet know what the value is.

Let me give you a real life example. Suppose you have a database that stores sales proposals. Suppose further that each proposal only has one sales person assigned and one client.  So your proposal table would have two foreign keys, one with the client ID and one with the sales rep ID.  However, at the time the record is created, a sales rep is not always assigned (because no one is free to work on it yet), so the client ID is filled in but the sales rep ID might be null.  In other words, usually you need the ability to have a null FK when you may not know its value at the time the data is entered, but you do know other values in the table that need to be entered. To allow nulls in an FK generally all you have to do is allow nulls on the field that has the FK. The null value is separate from the idea of it being an FK.

Whether it is unique or not unique relates to whether the table has a one-one or a one-many relationship to the parent table.  Now if you have a one-one relationship, it is possible that you could have the data all in one table, but if the table is getting too wide or if the data is on a different topic (the employee - insurance example @tbone gave for instance), then you want separate tables with a FK. You would then want to make this FK either also the PK (which guarantees uniqueness) or put a unique constraint on it.

Most FKs are for a one to many relationship and that is what you get from a FK without adding a further constraint on the field. So you have an order table and the order details table for instance. If the customer orders ten items at one time, he has one order and ten order detail records that contain the same orderID as the FK.

Comment: So that's intended to be better than having a fake sales person named "Unassigned"?

Comment: A comment. Nulls leave lots of room for errors in the query by folks who don't know how SQL (mis)handles 3VL . If a salesperson is truly not necessary for a certain r-table, just you don't include that record. A separate table can be "ProposalAssignedTo" or some such, with appropriate constraints. A query writer can then join to that table, and supply their own logic for whatever we want to do when a proposal doesn't have a salesperson. NULL doesn't just mean "we don't know" - it can be used for lots of things (which is why it's almost always a bad idea)

Comment: @ThomasWeller Referencing a fake salesperson ("Unassigned") makes the problem worse. I assume your salesperson table has multiple columns...? What Mr. Unassigned's social insurance number? Which department is he assigned to? Who is his boss? I hope you get my point: when you create an "Unassigned" salesperson you quickly discover that you traded `NULL` in one table for multiple `NULL`s in a different table.

Comment: @ThomasWeller You'll also have a problem if/when you need to localize your interface.

Comment: And then a joker comes along and names himself "Unassigned" and then he just became GOAT sales person.

Answer (score 53):

1 - [Yes, since at least SQL Server 2000.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933117%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

2 - Yes, as long as it's not a `UNIQUE` constraint or linked to a unique index.

Comment: That link is dead.

Comment: Even WaybackMachine hasn't any record. The oldest snapshot dates to 2016, but even then it shows, that the doc has been retired.

Answer (score 24):

Yes foreign key can be null as told above by senior programmers... I would add another scenario where Foreign key will required to be null....
suppose we have tables comments, Pictures and Videos in an application which allows comments on pictures and videos. In comments table we can have two Foreign Keys PicturesId, and VideosId along with the primary Key CommentId. So when you comment on a video only VideosId would be required and pictureId would be null... and if you comment on a picture only PictureId would be required and VideosId would be null...

Comment: I think there is a better way to solve this problem. Rather than creating new columns, you can have two columns, namely "id" and "type", which will contain the id and name of the foreign key table. Eg, id=1, type=Picture will represent link to Picture table with id 1. Advantage of using this solution is, you wont have to create new columns when comments are added to additional tables. Disadvantage will be no foreign key constraint on db level, rather the constraint will have to be app level.

Comment: @Agent: We've had this "solution" in production usage. Don't do it, it's terrible. Making queries becomes this mess of, "if it's type 1, join to this table, otherwise join to this". It was a nightmare for us. We ended up doing what this answer says and created a new column for each type of join. Creating columns is cheap. Pretty much it's only flaw is that lots of columns makes Toad hard to use, but that's just a flaw of Toad.

Comment: @FighterJet Rails provides with a great ORM framework which handles even complex queries with this solution.

Comment: @Agent: Maybe it can... but if you can make it simple, why make it complex? And maybe "nightmare" was the wrong word to use: it was just very inconvenient. We didn't suffer from data integrity problems (much).

Answer (score 16):

it depends on what role this `foreign key` plays in your relation.

1. if this `foreign key` is also a `key attribute` in your relation, then it can't be NULL
2. if this `foreign key` is a normal attribute in your relation, then it can be NULL.

Comment: What do you mean by `key attribute`?

Comment: @KwakuBiney, I think he means "if the field is mandatory in the record" (key attribute in the record might have been better).

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example using Oracle syntax:
First let's create a table COUNTRY

```
CREATE TABLE TBL_COUNTRY ( COUNTRY_ID VARCHAR2 (50) NOT NULL ) ;
ALTER TABLE TBL_COUNTRY ADD CONSTRAINT COUNTRY_PK PRIMARY KEY ( COUNTRY_ID ) ;
```

Create the table PROVINCE

```
CREATE TABLE TBL_PROVINCE(
PROVINCE_ID VARCHAR2 (50) NOT NULL ,
COUNTRY_ID  VARCHAR2 (50)
);
ALTER TABLE TBL_PROVINCE ADD CONSTRAINT PROVINCE_PK PRIMARY KEY ( PROVINCE_ID ) ;
ALTER TABLE TBL_PROVINCE ADD CONSTRAINT PROVINCE_COUNTRY_FK FOREIGN KEY ( COUNTRY_ID ) REFERENCES TBL_COUNTRY ( COUNTRY_ID ) ;
```

This runs perfectly fine in Oracle. Notice the COUNTRY_ID foreign key in the second table doesn't have "NOT NULL".

Now to insert a row into the PROVINCE table, it's sufficient to only specify the PROVINCE_ID. However, if you chose to specify a COUNTRY_ID as well, it must exist already in the COUNTRY table.

Answer (score 3):

By default there are no constraints on the foreign key, foreign key can be null and duplicate.

while creating a table / altering the table,  if you add any constrain of uniqueness or not null then only it will not allow the null/ duplicate values.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, "Non-identifying" relationships between Entities is part of ER-Model and is available in Microsoft Visio when designing ER-Diagram. This is required to enforce cardinality between Entities of type " zero or more than zero", or "zero or one". Note this "zero" in cardinality instead of "one" in "one to many".

Now, example of non-identifying relationship where cardinality may be "zero" (non-identifying) is when we say a record / object in one entity-A "may" or "may not" have a value as a reference to the record/s in another Entity-B.

As, there is a possibility for one record of entity-A to identify itself to the records of other Entity-B, therefore there should be a column in Entity-B to have the identity-value of the record of Entity-B. This column may be "Null" if no record in Entity-A identifies the record/s (or, object/s) in Entity-B.

In Object Oriented (real-world) Paradigm, there are situations when an object of Class-B does not necessarily depends (strongly coupled) on object of class-A for its existence, which means Class-B is loosely-coupled with Class-A such that Class-A may "Contain" (Containment) an object of Class-A, as opposed to the concept of object of Class-B must have (Composition) an object of Class-A, for its (object of class-B) creation.

From SQL Query point of view, you can query all records in entity-B which are "not null" for foreign-key reserved for Entity-B. This will bring all records having certain corresponding value for rows in Entity-A alternatively all records with Null value will be the records which do not have any record in Entity-A in Entity-B.

Answer (score 1):

> Can a Foreign key be NULL?

Existing answers focused on single column scenario. If we consider multi column foreign key we have more options using `MATCH [SIMPLE | PARTIAL | FULL]` clause defined in SQL Standard:

> [PostgreSQL-CREATE TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-createtable.html)
>
> A value inserted into the referencing column(s) is matched against the values of the referenced table and referenced columns using the given match type. There are three match types: MATCH FULL, MATCH PARTIAL, and MATCH SIMPLE (which is the default). **MATCH FULL** will not allow one column of a multicolumn foreign key to be null unless all foreign key columns are null; if they are all null, the row is not required to have a match in the referenced table. **MATCH SIMPLE** allows any of the foreign key columns to be null; if any of them are null, the row is not required to have a match in the referenced table. **MATCH PARTIAL** is not yet implemented.
>
> (Of course, NOT NULL constraints can be applied to the referencing column(s) to prevent these cases from arising.)

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE A(a VARCHAR(10), b VARCHAR(10), d DATE , UNIQUE(a,b));
INSERT INTO A(a, b, d) 
VALUES (NULL, NULL, NOW()),('a', NULL, NOW()),(NULL, 'b', NOW()),('c', 'b', NOW());

CREATE TABLE B(id INT PRIMARY KEY, ref_a VARCHAR(10), ref_b VARCHAR(10));

-- MATCH SIMPLE - default behaviour nulls are allowed
ALTER TABLE B ADD CONSTRAINT B_Fk FOREIGN KEY (ref_a, ref_b) 
REFERENCES A(a,b) MATCH SIMPLE;

INSERT INTO B(id, ref_a, ref_b) VALUES (1, NULL, 'b');  

-- (NULL/'x') 'x' value does not exists in A table, but insert is valid
INSERT INTO B(id, ref_a, ref_b) VALUES (2, NULL, 'x');  

ALTER TABLE B DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS B_Fk; -- cleanup

-- MATCH PARTIAL - not implemented
ALTER TABLE B ADD CONSTRAINT B_Fk FOREIGN KEY (ref_a, ref_b) 
REFERENCES A(a,b) MATCH PARTIAL;
-- ERROR:  MATCH PARTIAL not yet implemented

DELETE FROM B; ALTER TABLE B DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS B_Fk; -- cleanup

-- MATCH FULL nulls are not allowed
ALTER TABLE B ADD CONSTRAINT B_Fk FOREIGN KEY (ref_a, ref_b) 
REFERENCES A(a,b) MATCH FULL;

-- FK is defined, inserting NULL as part of FK
INSERT INTO B(id, ref_a, ref_b) VALUES (1, NULL, 'b');
-- ERROR:  MATCH FULL does not allow mixing of null and nonnull key values.

-- FK is defined, inserting all NULLs - valid
INSERT INTO B(id, ref_a, ref_b) VALUES (1, NULL, NULL);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=442ab05ec11c19a7a8d403e7bd1610ac)**

Answer (score -1):

I think it is better to consider the possible cardinality we have in the tables. 
We can have possible minimum cardinality zero. When it is optional, the minimum participation of tuples from the related table could be zero, Now you face the necessity of foreign key values to be allowed null.

But the answer is it all depends on the Business.

Answer (score -6):

The idea of a foreign key is based on the concept of referencing a value that already exists in the main table. That is why it is called a foreign key in the other table. This concept is called referential integrity. If a foreign key is declared as a null field it will violate the the very logic of referential integrity. What will it refer to? It can only refer to something that is present in the main table. Hence, I think it would be wrong to declare a foreign key field as null.

Comment: It can reference "nothing" or you don't know its value yet `NULL` , but what referential integrity says is that if it references "something" it must be there.

Answer (score -9):

I think foreign key of one table also primary key to some other table.So it won't allows nulls.So there is no question of having null value in foreign key.