# C# - The binary operator Equal is not defined for the types 'System.Int64'

Tags: c#, .net, parsing

I'm getting this error and I'm very confident about what cause it but not very sure how to fix it.

I am using `entity framework code first` and I have a foreign key in one of my entities which I on purpose set to `long?` :

```
public long? ClientId { get; set; }
public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
```

Then I use the data form the database that I create to fill a `DataGridView` and here comes the problem. I'm using custom searching/filtering through the elements of the `dgv` and the code for this custom filtering is inherited. It worked so fine till now but when I try to filter with `ClientID` I get the error for the post name.

I start debugging and saw this:

```
if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                        {//some code
else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(bool))
                        {//other code
else if(rule.Data.Equals("1") || rule.Data.ToLower().Equals("true"))
                            {//again some code
else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(Int32))
                        {//some code
...
```

And because my value is type `long?` i don't get in the conditions below so my code enters the default condition which is:

```
else
   {
       long value = 0;
       if (long.TryParse(rule.Data, out value))
   {..code
```

According to the debugger the parsing returns true because I get into the `if` body but then I recieve the error from above and the type of me property is `System.Nullable1[System.Int64]`.

I have a second foreign key which uses the exact same logic and everything works just fine with him. The only difference that I can see is that for the working case the type is `long` and for the error case the type is `long?`.

I want to leave the type `long?` but don't know if there's any workaround for this case.

Comment: So, you are receiving an error in the code you haven't shown us, am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: "You saw that code" where? What is the purpose of the method (the name of the method helps to identify). Another very important question: What is the error?

Comment: Yeah, the project is pretty big so I tried to isolate the problem. If I'm not understood then I guess I'll have to make it on my own. but fwi the code that call this method is `GridFilterResult<T> result = service.List(gridSettings);` . But I think that the prbolem is that I try to parse `long?` as `long` I tried to add a specific case for `long?` but it seems as if parsing to `long?` is not allowed...

Comment: Leron, tell us the error or exception please! :-) Also post the code that the exception happens on it.

Comment: Ok, now I'm sure that the problem is in `long?` even thou parsing to `long` returns `true`.

Comment: As I wrote in my post, it's in the title - `The binary operator Equal is not defined for the types 'System.Int64'`. I'm sorry that I have to work with code snippets but the code is too long. And I somewhat identified the error. I'm parsing `long?` with `long.TryParse` which seems to work but still there's a difference and I think the difference is this -`System.Nullable1[System.Int64]`If I must be more secific maybe the problem is how to change the type of `long?` to `long`...

Comment: Foreign keys really shouldn't be null.  You might want to rethink why you want to use `long?` in the first place.

Comment: Well, the solution has 5 projects and all of them are using the database created with the `EF`. From this point it's easier to change the code if you can than the structure of the DB. And when I was wondering about the nullable foreign key a lot of people wrote that it's nothing out of ordinary.

Comment: @juharr, why do you say that foreign keys shouldn't be null?

Comment: @omerschleifer As far as I know you can not setup a DB with a foreign key that allows nulls.  And even if you can set it up it really doesn't make sense.  The relationship is one-to-many.  The translation to code should result in one side having a collection of objects and the other side having a reference to the object whose collection they are a part of.  Allowing nulls means you have orphan objects and is likely a flaw in the design.

Comment: @juharr, I respectively disagree. See :    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573590/can-foreign-key-null-and-duplicate for the reasons why.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I've encountered a case where the generation of `T?` doesn't really work, but changing it to `Nullable<T>` does. Ie it generates code suitable for `long` but not for `long?`.

In your case:

```
public Nullable<long> ClientId { get; set; } // change long? to Nullable<long>
public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
```

Does that help?

Comment: Sorry this was a while ago. I'm not working for the same company anymore so I can't test your suggestion. Still if it works for some cases leave it here so it eventually could help someone else.