# Foreign key that can hold duplicate values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

The `product_rate_id` column in the following table needs to be referenced from another table as foreign key.
However, the `product_rates` TABLE must contain duplicate values for `product_rate_id`. (Legacy system, don’t ask why)

```
CREATE TABLE product_rates
(
    row_id             INT  IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    product_rate_id    INT NOT NULL,
    START_DATE         DATETIME NOT NULL,
    end_date           DATETIME,
   unit_rate          NUMERIC(18,6)
)
```

So the question is: can you have a column which is referenced as a foreign key by  another table contain duplicate values?
Is there any work around for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can foreign key NULL and duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573590/can-foreign-key-null-and-duplicate)

Comment: There's a good answer in the question above.  Short answer is a foreign key constraint does not have to be unique.

Comment: How do you create a non unique constraint?

Comment: @GoatCO I'm reading the question differently - I'm reading is as the column the foreign key _refers_ to (`product_rate_id`) is non-unique.  Those are two different questions.

Comment: `Col1 int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES OtherTable(Id_Field)`  in this case, `Col1` can have multiple duplicate values, `ID_Field` must have a unique constraint applied.

Comment: The product_rate_id column need to have duplicate rows. I guess Stanley has cleared thing up for me.

Comment: @DStanley Ah, un-delete then!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> can you have a column which is referenced as a foreign key by another table contain duplicate values?

No - a foreign key constraint must reference a unique key.

You can still keep a (non-foreign-key) reference to the `product_rate_id` value in related tables, but you'll have to decide *which* related record you want when querying (I'm assuming by using an effective date between `start_date` and `end_date`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not agree. You can have a PK like Order.id_order, and a FK to Order_Detail.id_order, having more than one row (order details) associated to a unique id_order value (FK not-unique or duplicated).

Comment: @EugenioF.MartinezPacheco That was not the question - the question was can you have a foreign key that references `product_rate_id` which is not unique.

Comment: Ok, I see, you are right  @d-stanley :P..... Maybe "product_rate_id" should be replaced by a surrogate key as PK, or choose a composite key for the FK instead... Regards!