# Can a foreign key be null or left empty?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, null

**My problem:**

Although my database is rather complex I'm just including the `car` and `customer` tables.

So I have a `customer` table with the relevant details and the `customer_id` as the `primary key`.

Now, within the `car` table i want to have a `foreign key` linked to the `customer_id`, so within the `car` table i can see who owns what. The problem is what if the `car` hasn't been brought yet?

As far as i can see the foreign key must have a `customer_id` to be added to the table.

Am i missing something here or am i way off track, i read something about linked tables?
Can a `foreign key` be `null`?

---

One other thing, how do i set up rules like:

'A `car` can only have 1 `manufacturer` (which is a separate table linked with a `fk`)'? I'm guessing that's done with php correct?

If anyone wants a pic of the databases current ERD, i have one.

Comment: Yes, FK can be have NULL. For your second question `A car can only have 1 manufacturer` ... you can use `CHECK CONSTRAINT`

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, check this reference: [Can a foreign key be NULL and/or duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573590/can-foreign-key-null-and-duplicate)

Your question will be flagged as a duplicate because of it.

---

About the second one:

The relationship **can** and **should** be handled by both `php` and `database` for safety purposes (especially the last one). That **guarantees that your data won't get corrupted** in case someone "forget" about the relationship.

They are just table's columns that hold an ID of another table. You could use a "String", "Date" or whatever you think of to relate 1 entity to another, but the safest and faster option would be just using another entity's ID.

**Why?**

`Primary_keys` **must** be **unique**, that guarantees you have no duplicates (think of them as a universal IDentification inside your context),  and `foreign_keys` must belong to another entity in another table. You **can't use a value that doesn't belong to any entity in the other table** nor **delete one entity who has it's ID in some other** `foreign_key` **in some other entity** (you will have to delete all the "childrens" before deleting the "parent", otherwise they would be "orphans")

More about those keys is in that [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573590/can-foreign-key-null-and-duplicate) I have posted above and any other rich references you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/) and [googling](http://www.google.com) it

---

Of course you could just ignore it and don't handle it at all, but **it's an awful practice** and it won't be recommended. 
`and I will hunt you down if I find out you did this... hahah`