# Database normalization of an entity with varied properties

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-normalization

In my application I have an entity, table, called `actions` with varied properties. To clarify the case, the following is the table `actions` structure:

1. id,
2. status_id(not null),
3. section_id(not null),
4. job_id (not null)
5. equipment_id (**null**),
6. cause_id (**null**),
7. solution_id (**null**),
8. created_at,
9. closed_at,
10. action_type (not null) char(3)

Where all fields suffixed with `_id` are foreign keys and the `action_type` is very limited and defined list of actions types, so I defined it in a configuration file i.e there is no database entity for `action_type`.

My question is more general than this one: [Can a foreign key be NULL and/or duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573590/can-a-foreign-key-be-null-and-or-duplicate) where I'm asking about normalization principal.

In my case, some action types has no need, for example, for `equipment_id`, where others need `equipment_id` but not need both `cause_id` and `solution_id`, etc

In my database design, the `actions` table looks like Many to Many conjugation table.

The above design allows, easily, to get many statistics data about sections and jobs without need to perform complex join queries.

My question is: Does my normalization and design correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "normalization"? That word is used to mean a lot of different things. Instead of that word, please explain what you are trying to achieve and why. And if you are refering to a particular use of it, please give a reference. Also, please rephrase the unclear "some action types has no need, for example, for equipment_id, where others need equipment_id but not need both cause_id and solution_id, etc".

Comment: @philipxy well it works like  actions log table. That log is going to record some data about actions including, its type, equipment used , defect, cause, solution if any of them applicable.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. By "explain what you are trying to achieve and why" I meant, by using "normalization".

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  A foreign key containing a NULL represents a case where a relationship is optional, and the relationship is not present in this instance.

In your case,  there may be entries where there is simply no corresponding equipment, and equipment_id is accordingly left NULL.  When a join is done to the reference table,  rows with NULL in the foreign key will simply drop out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if these _id are not so important so in normalization you can set them as null or remove them :)