# Can MySQL automatically convert empty strings to NULL?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, sql-null

There is an excellent SO on MySQL empty strings versus NULL here, [MySQL, better to insert NULL or empty string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267999/mysql-better-to-insert-null-or-empty-string), however it doesn't take in to account 'uniformity' - i.e. if you want to have just one choice in your tables (i.e. empty string OR NULL), which should it be?

My question is, can I get MySQL to automatically store empty strings as NULLs?

After reading the previous SO I am generally inclined to store NULL but the problem is that I have a lot of PHP forms with optional fields, and (when left blank) these return empty strings.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can enclose your strings with [`NULLIF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_nullif).

You use it like this:

```
NULLIF('test','') --> returns 'test'
NULLIF(''    ,'') --> returns NULL
```

Comment: [NULLIF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif)

Comment: If the first and second parameters of `NULLIF(string1, string2)` match, `NULL` is returned.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to NULLIF you could set the default to NULL and just not pass empty fields along.