# MySQL Null or empty fields - New Database Design

Tags: mysql

I'm designing a new database and currently there a many fields that end up with the value NULL.

I've read about NULL vs "" and I think that "" is preferred.

Should I go to the effort to ensure there are no NULL values - it would only take a few hours?

Is this worth the effort - Note: I will be working with this database for many years to come.

thx

Comment: personally I don't like `nulls` unless really needed. Any column with `null` allowed is additional `null` checking code.

Comment: Well that depends on your `business constraints` if your FR requires the value to not nullable, then you have to enforce it with a rule 'NOT NULL' and if not then leave it be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start will null values and see how it goes. I think it's a simple enough procedure to update where is null to "".

This question is very similar and has a great answer arguing between null and "". [MySQL, better to insert NULL or empty string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267999/mysql-better-to-insert-null-or-empty-string)

Answer (score 2):

A simple hint: If you "end up" with many fields being *NULL* in a *table*, this is probably the sign that you should split your table in two, using a [`JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) operation to retrieve data when needed...

---

Concerning `NULL` vs `""` remember few things:

- `NULL` is the standard SQL way to say "non existent data"
- `NULL` is usable both for text and non-text columns. `""` is for text-only
- aggregate functions like `COUNT()` will ignore NULL values but not `""`
- Column having `UNIQUE` [index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index) allow several rows having a `NULL` value. But *not* several rows having `""` as value