# Difference between NULL and Blank Value in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to check for a value of a particular Column named `RESULT` is blank or not.

When I check  with `if RESULT IS NULL`, the query failed, but When I checked `RESULT=''`, it worked.

What is difference between two.

please explain.

```
"UPDATE RLS_TP_2012_03 a, RLS_TP_2012_03 b SET a.COMMENT=b.COMMENT where b.TCODE='T1199' and  a.GROUPNAME='xyz' and a.HLABNO=b.HLABNO and a.RESULT =''; ";   
"UPDATE RLS_TP_2012_03 a, RLS_TP_2012_03 b SET a.COMMENT=b.COMMENT where b.TCODE='T1199' and  a.GROUPNAME='xyz' and a.HLABNO=b.HLABNO and a.RESULT is NULL; "
```

Comment: NULL is NULL, blank is blank....Period.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL, better to insert NULL or empty string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267999/mysql-better-to-insert-null-or-empty-string)

Comment: NULL means no value. Blank means a value that is blank

Answer (score 38, accepted):

1. `NULL` is an absence of a value. An empty string is a value, but is just empty. `NULL` is special to a database.
2. `NULL` has no bounds, it can be used for `string`, `integer`, `date`, etc. fields in a database.
3. `NULL` isn't allocated any memory, the `string` with `NULL` value is just a pointer which is pointing to nowhere in memory. however, Empty IS allocated to a memory location, although the value stored in the memory is `""`.

Comment: Does this mean that NULL technically uses up less space/memory, thus better for performance wise? E.g. if you had nvarchar(max) with a NULL value versus an empty string?

Answer (score 6):

In tri-value logic, NULL should be used to represent "unknown" or "not applicable" An empty column should represent "known but empty".

Some DBMS products don't follow this convention all the time but I consider them deficient. Yes, you know who you are, Oracle :-)

In addition, while NULL can be put into any column type (ignoring `not null` clauses for now), you cannot put an "empty" value into a non-character field (like `integer`).

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @ricky, NULL can never equal NULL, but an empty string is always equal to an empty string. That's a huge difference when you are trying to match records.

Answer (score 0):

NULL in database systems - No value set for the field. A void

NULL (character) - A blank, an ASCII/Unicode character with no graphical representation. But it is present in code page as a character constant '\0' with a character value 0 or 000.