# NULL values in where condition is not working

Tags: mysql, sql, select, null

I have encountered a weird problem in a MySQL query. This following query is returning me 0 result whereas there are many rows which should be returned. the query is

```
SELECT DISTINCT SKU, EAN, URL, CID 
  FROM tab_comp_data 
 WHERE status =''
```

And in many rows there are NULL values in STATUS column but it returns me no rows.

I have tried some other way round.

```
SELECT DISTINCT SKU, EAN, URL, CID 
  FROM tab_comp_data 
 WHERE status <>'INACT'
```

this also returns me no rows.

P.S. the STATUS column can only be `NULL` or `'INACT'`

Comment: Did you try `status <>' '`

Comment: This is the best question ever to get a thousan replies in less tha 10 seconds

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444518/difference-between-null-and-blank-value-in-mysql may help

Comment: Only Oracle sometimes treats empty strings as NULL  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I you want to query for `NULL` values, you should use the `IS NULL` operator.

So, your query should look like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SKU, EAN, URL, CID 
  FROM tab_comp_data
 WHERE status IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

if the value of status is null you have to use `is null`. That is different from `=''`

```
select DISTINCT SKU, EAN, URL, CID from tab_comp_data WHERE status is null
```

Answer (score 1):

`null` is not a value - it's a lack thereof. As such, it cannot be evaluated with the equality (`=`) or inequality (`<>`) operators. Instead, it should be checked explicitly with the `is` operator:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sku, ean, url, cid 
FROM   tab_comp_data 
WHERE  status IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `is NULL`

```
select DISTINCT SKU, EAN, URL, CID from tab_comp_data WHERE status is NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT SKU, EAN, URL, CID 
  FROM tab_comp_data 
 WHERE status IS NULL
```

Use is null , instead of `=''`