# NOT NULL returning NULL values

Tags: mysql, null

When i run the following query i get 12 rows, when i should have 6 (the ones that are not null in 'firsts') any reason why iam getting all 12? Becuase they are future dates they are empty but i wanted to have the table display the dates for whole year on the table.   i have used varchar and not int for the firsts which isnt good practice i know.

```
SELECT * 
FROM office_figures 2016 
WHERE date_figures=2017 AND firsts IS NOT NULL
```

[image: mysql table]

Comment: `firsts` are empty and not `NULL`, you must populate them with `NULL` or set default to `NULL`.

Comment: when you say populate with null..do you mean actually put 'null' in the cells?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the firsts that you don't want to be there aren't null, they might be just empty strings ''.
Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM office_figures 2016 
WHERE date_figures=2017 AND firsts IS NOT NULL AND firsts != ''
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked . i really need to know this now without asking,,can you point me to a reference book that taught you ?

Comment: Sorry for the late late late response, I've learnt this from experience, happned to me some times and it was hard to figure it out

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM office_figures 2016 
WHERE date_figures=2017 AND firsts IS NOT NULL AND firsts !="";
```

You need to check for an empty value in column as well as "" != NULL.

- Null is an absence of a value. An empty string is a value, but is
  just empty. Null is special to a database.
- Null has no bounds, it can be used for string, integer, date, etc.
  fields in a database.
- NULL isn't allocated any memory, the string with NUll value is just a
  pointer which is pointing to nowhere in memory. however, Empty IS
  allocated to a memory location, although the value stored in the
  memory is "".

[Difference between NULL and Blank Value in Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444518/difference-between-null-and-blank-value-in-mysql) 
Check the above link to know more.