# Should I always set default value to `NULL` in MySQL databases?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I was working with a particularly large table (22 fields) and those fields are not always filled on create. In fact on first create, only 9 fields are set.

I was not surprised to get an error that I’m trying to create a row with undefined fields which don’t have default values. I saw two ways of fixing this:

1. Go in the database and set every field to have default value set to `null`
2. When calling `create`, insert `""` for string values, `0` for integer values, etc.

I decided to go with the first option as it is quicker and less messy.

Now I have to go in the database and change each field to have default value of either `null` or `current timestamp` if working with `date` or `time`.

Is this really the best approach? Is there no way of leaving these fields empty?

Comment: That depends on your data model. Sometimes you want to state explicitely, that the value is undefined, sometimes you want to pass default value like 0 or empty string.

Comment: Don't use empty strings or 0 for missing values, that's a mess.

Comment: @px1mp Lets say i dont want to do that. Is it a good practice to set default values to null or not?

Comment: 'those fields are not always filled on create' - ?? no columns are filled on a create - what did you mean by this?

Comment: @jarlh Yes it is, i couldnt think of an alternative solution to these 2 and i chose the first one (set default as null) instead of the latter one.

Comment: @P.Salmon I guess i misspoke. They are not filled on inser. Im working with a CRUD api so i messed up the terminology.

Comment: Still not with you - if you insert values into specific columns then the remaining columns will be set to/default to null without having to specify default null in table definition. see https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/r19QtWxwibPXmWXYdreq87/0

Comment: @P.Salmon Not really. If you call `INSERT INTO tab (value1 = 1, value2 = 2)` and tab has a `value3` field, if you dont specify a default value in the table structure when creating the table, i will not allow you to insert into that table if you dont specify all the fields (value1, value2 and value3). At least in my scenario that was the case.

Comment: Im using SQLAlchemy o run the queries.
My database is hosted on PhpMyAdmin which as far as i know uses innodb as a storage engine.

Comment: True but if you insert into tab(value1,value2) values (1,2) - then it will - or is it a feature of SQLAlchemy that you cannot specify columns in the insert?  or are you saying you don't want to? BTW you should tag SQLAlchemy

Comment: @P.Salmon Im actually using that format of inserting:
`INSERT INTO tab (val1, val2) VALUES (%s, %s)` and then i pass in 2 parameters to substutute for each `%s` - a way to defend against `XSS`.

It could be that `SQLAlchemy` converts `(val1, val2) VALUES (1, 2)` into `(val1 = 1, val2 = 2)` after it binds parameters and checks for `xss` but i dont think that is likely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are inserting rows with 9 values out of 22 values set, then presumably the other 13 columns are nullable or should have a `default` value.

If there is no obvious default, then the correct data model is to have `NULL`able columns.  That is what the data is and how it should be represented.

Although I don't advocate its use, I will note that `''` works for almost all data types.  It is converted to a `0` for numbers and to a `0` date for date/time values.  Under some circumstances, this can be a handy way to assign a value.

Comment: Rick said **"NULL isn't allocated any memory, ... Empty IS allocated to a memory location..."** from his reply ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444518/difference-between-null-and-blank-value-in-mysql ). I think for larger tables such as 22 fields, this is one way to save space but I guess this will slow your search performance.