# SQL Difference between NULL, "", and blank?

Tags: mysql, sql, null

What is the difference between these?

The beginning part is as follows:

```
SELECT p.Name
     , p.DOB
     , ea.mailaddress
  FROM Mall p
  LEFT 
  JOIN mailaddresss ea
```

And differ both of these ending lines:

```
ON p.MallEntityID = ea.MallEntityID
WHERE ea.mailaddress LIKE 'NULL'
```

and

```
ON p.MallEntityID = ea.MallEntityID 
AND ea.mailaddress LIKE 'NULL'
```

Sample data is as follows:

```
name mailaddress Mallentity
Bob                   1
Joe   ""              2
Dib   NULL            3
Shay  8892            4
```

Comment: Actually, there is *NOTHING IN COMMON* between the empty string `""`, the string `'NULL'`, and the SQL (lack of) value "NULL".  They're all completely different.  `ea.mailaddress LIKE ‘NULL’` belongs in your "WHERE" clause, not the "JOIN".  Look here: https://dataschool.com/how-to-teach-people-sql/difference-between-where-and-on-in-sql/

Comment: Please don't use Word to format code

Comment: The first query is an inner join. The second is an outer join. `Like 'string'` is the same as `= 'string'`, unless using a case sensitive collation (highly unlikely)

Comment: Incidentally, the test for null is `IS NULL`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between NULL and Blank Value in Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444518/difference-between-null-and-blank-value-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

The first query will find Malls with or without email addresses that have the string 'null'. The second one won't include them.