# ORA-01400: Can't insert NULL into ("repository name"."MD_PROJECTS"."ID")

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-migration, oracle12c

We are migrating a MySQL database to an Oracle 12c database using SQL Developer 4.0.3.16.

After creating a repository we had an error (unable to create repository because it still exists, delete it first.). There was no repository so we just tried again and it worked, repository was created.

Now we are connected to our source database (MySQL), our target database (Oracle) (see picture) and we have another connection with our migrating user (migrepo) to our target database.

[image]

Now we are having the following error over and over again..:

[image]

(English: ORA-01400: Can't insert NULL into ("MIGREPO"."MD_PROJECTS"."ID"))

Can anyone help us?

Comment: are you moving data or schema structure and data?

Comment: schema structure and data

Comment: If that column is a primary key, or even if it just has a `NOT NULL` constraint on it, you won't be able to insert a `NULL` into it. Take a look at the table's constraints, you might have to drop one or more to accomplish what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Another possibility is that you are trying to insert not an explicit `NULL` value, but an empty string. Oracle considers the empty string `''` to be the same as `NULL`. MySQL, on the other hand, does support empty strings as distinct from `NULL`s. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267999/mysql-better-to-insert-null-or-empty-string

Comment: I am not trying to insert anything but just trying to migrate a database.. if i drop the constraint on primary key 'id' it gives only more errors.

Comment: `I am not trying to insert anything but just trying to migrate a database` - if you're migrating the data you're inserting. Given that `id` is a primary key, you're either inserting a `NULL` or an empty string (which Oracle views as a `NULL`).

Comment: This poor old question might finally have an answer: [migration from mysql to oracle hits ora-01400](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67638360/migration-from-mysql-to-oracle-hits-ora-01400)

Answer (score 0):

Your table MIGREPO.MD_PROJECTS has a column named ID on it which is either a primary key or has a NOT NULL constraint on it (or perhaps both). Something in the code being run is trying to put NULL into this ID column, which the constraint(s) will not allow.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks, does anyone where the table MD_PROJECTS is used for? (it is a standard table in a migration repository..)

Comment: I am running into the same error with SQL Developer version 18.4.0.376

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I was trying to migrate it as sysdba. Created new user and migrated without errors.

Comment: Could you please elaborate the solution?

Comment: We have stuck with same issue. Need some information. Is new User created for MySql? What permission are given to user.?

Answer (score -1):

Better try changing your Oracle column as `NOT NULL`, and while you are converting, select the option as `APPEND` for what if table exist. It will solve the problem.