# migration from mysql to oracle hits ora-01400

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, dbmigrate

I followed  instruction for migrating MySQL to oracle, at the last step(press finish), we hit the following error: Migration actions have failed, check the migration reports for details: capture Classic capture ora-01400: cannot insert null into ("MIGRATION_REPO", "MD_PROJECTS", "ID")

Comment: PLease edit the question and post any relevant code or something

Comment: "click finish"     What tool are you using?  What did you discover when you "check the migration reports for details"?  The error itself sounds pretty self-explanatory ... the target table has a column with a NOT NULL constraint, and the source data has a null value for that column.

Comment: I am using SQL developer to migrate my DB schema and data from MySQL to Oracle, that's when this error occurs

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error and finally determined that, for me, this is a permissions issue. When the repository was created it generated a generic error, but it looked like the repository was created. But something was missing, and it turns out that my user didn't have the "CREATE VIEW" privilege. Once that was added, I recreated the migration repository, and the migration worked.

Permissions are spelled out here:

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/RPTUG/migration.htm#RPTUG41484

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by creating a new user and giving it the necessary permissions to allow you to migrate:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO MySQL_Oracle_crimes;
GRANT DBA TO MySQL_Oracle_crimes;
```

It is worth clarifying that for it to work you must do everything from 0, that is, recreate your user and delete the connections in sql developer since there are a lot of error logs left,  I tried to truncate but it did not work, so I did the process from 0 but now with my user with privileges and roles.