# mySQL adding column with NULL values

Tags: mysql

I am using mySQL and am trying to get my head around the difference between NULL and empty.  If I add a column to my table using...

```
alter table data add result VARCHAR(4);
```

Then every field in the column is automatically populated with NULL.

Does this take up any more space than an empty field?  How could I add that column with blank values instead?

Comment: Here is a better glance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267999/mysql-better-to-insert-null-or-empty-string

Answer (score 0):

You can use [default](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_default.asp), if you don;t like nulls, but Null is more descriptive:

```
alter table data add result VARCHAR(4) DEFAULT ''
```

Generally you should be using null, as it means -none has set a value to this column.

As for the space I am not aware is MySQL is treating empty values, but I assume that NULL takes less space, because NULL is generally a singleton in most languages.