# Difference between varchar and varchar2 in SQL

Tags: sql

What is the Difference between varchar and varchar2 in SQL. Please explain in detail with some good example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between varchar and varchar2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171196/what-is-the-difference-between-varchar-and-varchar2)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Varchar2 is specific to Oracle.

The most significant nonstandard behavior of varchar2 is that an empty string (`''`) is the same as null.

In standard SQL, null is not the same as any string literal, not even the empty string.

Comment: +1 Probably worth mentioning that in Oracle, a condition testing whether `Field = ''` always evaluates as NULL (ie. never true), even if `Field` is '' (ie. NULL).

Comment: @Mark: Thanks, that's a good point.  Whereas in standard SQL, `Field = ''` can be true.

Answer (score 2):

they behave the same, though varchar2 is recommended:

> Currently VARCHAR behaves exactly the
>   same as VARCHAR2. However, this type
>   should not be used as it is reserved
>   for future usage.

[Source](http://www.orafaq.com/faq/what_is_the_difference_between_varchar_varchar2_and_char_data_types)

Answer (score 0):

Leigh Riffel on the DBA StackExchange gives the most detailed and precise overview I have read on the difference between VARCHAR and VARCHAR2: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/1303