# Error while creating TABLE in database

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax-error, ddl, create-table

I am using oracle 10g ex to learn so here is my code

```
CREATE TABLE MINE 
(
    NAME VARCHAR(10),
    ID INT(3) PRIMARY KEY 
);
```

and my error is

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis.

but I don't where I missed the right parenthesis. There is any other chance or something I have to know to solve this issue.

Answer (score 5):

`INT` does not need a size - it is an alias for `NUMBER(38)`.

```
CREATE TABLE MINE 
(
    NAME VARCHAR(10),
    ID   INT PRIMARY KEY 
);
```

However, what you probably want is to use [`VARCHAR2`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1171196/1509264) and `NUMBER` types:

```
CREATE TABLE MINE 
(
    NAME VARCHAR2(10),
    ID   NUMBER(3,0) PRIMARY KEY 
);
```

And now is the time to get into good habits - you probably also want to name your constraints:

```
CREATE TABLE MINE 
(
    NAME VARCHAR2(10),
    ID   NUMBER(3,0) CONSTRAINT mine__id__pk PRIMARY KEY 
);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `int` datatype doesn't take a size argument:

```
CREATE TABLE MINE 
(
    NAME VARCHAR(10),
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY -- Here!
);
```

Answer (score -2):

create table Mine(name varchar(10),Id number(20) PRIMARY KEY);

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.