# Oracle: Invalid Datatype Error on Create Table

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I'm trying to simply create an Oracle table and I'm getting an invalid datatype error, but it seems that's there nothing wrong with my create statement (unless I'm completely overlooking something).

```
    CREATE TABLE SCRIPT_LINE
    (
      ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
      EPISODE_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
      LINE_NUMBER INTEGER,
      RAW_TEXT VARCHAR(4000),
      TIMESTAMP NUMERIC,
      SPEAKING_LINE BOOLEAN,
      CHARACTER_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
      LOCATION_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
      CHARACTER VARCHAR(500),
      LOCATION VARCHAR(500),
      SPOKEN_WORD VARCHAR(4000),
      WORD_COUNT INTEGER
   );
```

Any idea where the error could be? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also - see the [difference between `VARCHAR` and `VARCHAR2`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171196/what-is-the-difference-between-varchar-and-varchar2).

Comment: @MT0: there is no difference VARCHAR is a synonym for VARCHAR2

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name There is no current implementation difference but `VARCHAR` is a placeholder for the ANSI standard `VARCHAR` which Oracle does not currently support (so has aliased to `VARCHAR2`) but may choose to support in later versions. There is a semantic difference between having an empty string and an unknown (`NULL`) representing the same thing and distinct things; so, even though it is not currently supported, the OP should understand the difference and consider future-proofing their application so that the most-appropriate type is used for if the ANSI standard is implemented.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle does not have a BOOLEAN datatype

Comment: Thanks for that. Yet it was a highlighted word in my developer console, which led me to believe it existed.

Comment: `BOOLEAN` is a valid type in PL/SQL - but it is not a valid type in the Oracle RDBMS engine. So it kind of depends on where you're at. :-) Personally, when I need a Yes/No kind of thing I use a `VARCHAR2(1) NOT NULL CHECK(whatever_field IN ('Y', 'N'))`. Works well enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

As Oracle does not support Boolean, the best alternative would be char(1)
 Y/N. alternatively use number (1) 0/1