# MySQL Alter Query

Tags: mysql

I want to add a column in Customers table. The name of the column which I want to add, is Phone_no. Now if I want to add the country code along with the Phone_no field , then what would be the data type of Phone_no ? e.g. the Phone_no is +918884560909 , Then what would be the data type of Phone_no field?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the number with special symbol like `+`, then use varchar for it like:

```
varchar(20)
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the difference between Varchar and Varchar2??

Comment: There is no varchar2 data type in mysql, that's an oracle data type.

Comment: varchar2 is present in oracle only. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171196/what-is-the-difference-between-varchar-and-varchar2

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer one field name it as varchar(expected_size). If you prefer two fields you can name one field as country code (varchar) and other as phone_no(number). Go through Oracle documentation for all available datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

`ALTER TABLE Customers ADD COLUMN Phone-no varchar(13);`

You could just store number without `+`. In that case you could store number as `bigint`

Comment: Storing a phone number as bigint is often a bad idea since it will drop leading zeroes.

Comment: yeah, You are right it would be better to store them as varchar.