# ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision

Tags: sql, oracle

```
   Create TABLE Customer(
   id number NOT NULL,
   Name varchar(200) NOT NULL,
   Address varchar(200) NOT NULL,
   Salary number(10,2) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT Customer_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
    );



     INSERT INTO Customer (id,Name, Address, Salary)
     VALUES (2, 'Tom B. Erichsen', 'Skagen 21', 30000.00);
```

getting an error ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision when trying to insert values into created table

Comment: Oracle != MySQL

Comment: How do you have ORA errors in MySQL?

Comment: The posted code works for me. Is there possibly a trigger on `Customer` that is not in the question?

Comment: It's actually impossible that it doesn't work if you have nothing else that could interfere. Your salary consists of 7 digits which is less than 10. Are you sure the table hasn't been created before your script and you are getting an error while creating it?

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing varchar with varchar2.

The other suggestion I have is putting a limit on id number.
Examples being:

```
Address varchar2(200) NOT NULL,
id number (5) NOT NULL
```

Unfortunately, as my reputation is too low, where does the application you are using actually pinpoint the error is occurring?  That would help you narrow it down.

Comment: [`VARCHAR` is currently a synonym for `VARCHAR2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1171200/1509264) so changing one for the other will make zero difference. [`NUMBER`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/datatype.htm#sthref3810) has 38 digits of precision - restricting it to `NUMBER(5)`, a lower precision, will not help the OP who has the problem `value larger than specified precision`.