# Error in primary key in sqlplus?

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I am beginner in sql.I am using sqlplus to run the sql query .I used simple query but it shows an error like **"MISSING RIGHT PARENTHESIS"**.My objective is to create the  autoincrement primary key .Can anyone solve the error?Thanks in advance...

```
create table student(rollno int identity(1,1) primary key,
                     name varchar(20),marks int);
```

Comment: That is invalid for Oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm#CJAECCFH

Comment: Which flavor of SQL are you using?  "sqlplus" implies Oracle but "identity" is a SQL Server concept.  They don't mix.

Comment: @Stilgar - Oracle 12c now has an identity concept, but the syntax used by the OP remains SQL Server's version not Oracles.

Comment: Since when Oracle has `IDENTITY(1, 1)`???  Read the documentation!!!

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle, the rollno column could be defined as NUMBER(0010) and primary key.
Then you would need to add an ON INSERT trigger to populate rollno from a SEQUENCE.  There are many samples of triggers and sequences on this site.

Answer (score 0):

In oracle 12 you can use a identity column to automatically fill your ID

```
CREATE TABLE students
(
    "ID" NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999 
    INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 , 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(20), 
    "MARKS" NUMBER(2,0),
    CONSTRAINT PK_STUDENTS PRIMARY KEY (ID) ENABLE 
);
/
```

This creates a table without any triggers needed and automatically fills the id column (of not specified with a value) with the next number up to 99999...

If you're using oracle 11 and below, you need a trigger on insert and assign a value (custom_sequence.nextval) to the id column.

```
CREATE TABLE students
(
    "ID" NUMBER(5,0) not null,
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(20),
    "MARKS" NUMBER(2,0),
    CONSTRAINT PK_STUDENTS PRIMARY KEY (ID) ENABLE 
);
/

CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_STUDENTS INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1;
/
TRIGGER TC_students
before insert on students
for each row
begin
    if (:new.id is null) then
        select SEQ_students.nextval into :new.id from dual;
    end if;
end;
/
```

[And please use VARCHAR2.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171196/what-is-the-difference-between-varchar-and-varchar2-in-oracle)