# SQL Error: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier in line 4

Tags: oracle11g, ora-00904

I was working in sql command line and got this error ORA-00904 when i queried to create a table

[image: Query Screenshot]

I tried various inputs and got the same error in line 4.
Help me out.

Comment: share the screenshot of error and query you are using @Hiteshr Ram

Comment: Click the Query Screenshot. I got the code corrected. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a table

Then this would work :

```
CREATE TABLE DATA
(
  ID INT NOT NULL,
  NAME VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL
);
```

But this would raise an ORA-00904 :

```
CREATE TABLE DATA
(
  ID INT NOT NULL,
  NAME VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
);
```

The difference?
After that last comma, something more is expected.
Yet, all it finds is a round bracket.
Hence, the error.

Comment: @HiteshRam Notice that I changed the VARCHAR to a VARCHAR2.  You can read more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171196/).

Comment: Please accept this answer if this solved your question/problem so it can be treated as a closed question. Give credit where credit is due.

Comment: @HiteshRam Btw, you could give that ID an IDENTITY. So that you don't have to insert the ID numbers yourself. You can read more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361/).  And quoting table names or field names isn't really mandatory. It's fine to leave them unquoted as long the name doesn't contain spaces, and it's not some restricted key word.