# strange behavior with 'IN' clause works

Tags: sql, oracle, null, behavior, string

i found this site: [here](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-22_11-5319615.html)

its very well described why it works and why not.

but my question is a little different.

```
select 'true' from dual where 'test' not in ('test2','');
```

why does this query not returing a row?
is `''` handled like `null`?

thx for your help

Comment: I'm not sure (I'm a SQL Server person) but I think Oracle does handle '' as null.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Oracle 9i treat an empty string as NULL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203493/why-does-oracle-9i-treat-an-empty-string-as-null)

Comment: @APC - Not really. This question is `does it...?` not `why does it...?`

Comment: @MartinSmith - well I think the answers to that question also answer this question.  So to that extent it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your suspicions [were correct](http://www.thunderguy.com/semicolon/2003/04/26/oracle-empty-string-null/).

So your query is basically

```
WHERE 'test' <> 'test2' and  'test' <> Null
```

Which evaluates as

```
WHERE true and unknown
```

Which is `unknown`

```
select * from dual where '' = '';
```

will give the same (lack of) results

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in Oracle an empty string is a NULL.