# Wasn't there a switch to toggle Oracles empty varchar2 - null behavior?

Tags: null, oracle10g, string, varchar2

As everybody working with Oracle knows, it an empty Varchar2 will result in a NULL value when put into a Varchar2 column.

I (and a coworker as well) thought we had read about a parameter that could be set in the database to change that behavior and actually differentiate between null values and empty Strings.

Is there such a parameter in the new versions? (We think since 10g)

Or is there a parameter which we might confuse with it with?

Comment: I don't think there is... See also the answers to tgus question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203493/why-does-oracle-9i-treat-an-empty-string-as-null

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, Oracle internally stores empty strings and nulls identically, so it **cannot** distinguish between them whether it wants to or not!  Both are stored as a zero character count and no other data.

Comment: Correct - that's one reason it's VARCHAR2; VARCHAR is reserved for if someday Oracle implements ANSI-compliant empty-string behavior.