# Can Oracle PL/SQL evaluate an integer as a boolean value?

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

Given `v_ssn_ind INTEGER := IF TRIM(p_ssn) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END IF;`

I know I can do this:  `IF v_ssn_ind=1 THEN…`

But can I do short-circuit evaluation, ie: `IF v_ssn_ind THEN…` ?

Comment: And, for bonus points, is it any faster or slower?

Comment: the expression `IF v_ssn_ind THEN` doesn't make sense (and won't compile if I'm not mistaken) unless `v_ssn_ind` is declared as a boolean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, what you are talking about does not appear to have anything to do with [short-circuit evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900631/does-oracle-use-short-circuit-evaluation/8900752#8900752).  Short-circuit evaluation would be when code like

```
IF( quick_condition AND slow_condition )
THEN
  <<do something>>
END IF;
```

evaluates the second slow condition if and only if the initial quick condition evaluates to TRUE.

Second, your assignment of a value to `v_ssn_ind` is not syntactically valid.

Third, no, you cannot say

```
IF <<integer variable>>
THEN
```

because that would not make sense.  What value would evaluate to TRUE and what value would evaluate to FALSE?  If 0 is FALSE and 1 is TRUE, for example, what would 17 translate to?

If you are declaring some sort of indicator variable, it would generally make sense to use a `BOOLEAN` data type rather than an integer.  If you use a boolean, then you can do

```
IF <<boolean variable>>
THEN
```

because that eliminates the ambiguity.  This won't be any faster than adding the `= TRUE` to your IF condition however.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit the title post and question--what is more appropriate than "short-circuit evaluation"?

Answer (score 0):

I discourage you from putting any logic into a declaration block, in my opinion it makes code less clear.

Instead `IF` you can use `CASE` statement.

```
...
    v_ssn_ind INTEGER;
BEGIN
    v_ssn_ind := CASE TRIM(p_ssn) IS NULL WHEN TRUE THEN 0 ELSE 1 END;
...
```

But personally I would chose `BOOLEAN` type for `v_ssn_ind`

```
...
    v_ssn_ind BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
    v_ssn_ind := TRIM(p_ssn) IS NOT NULL;
...
```

Comment: Personally, I would expect a variable named "_ind" to refer to an index of some sort. Perhaps renaming the variable to something like `v_ssn_is_not_null` would make more sense.

Comment: You are right, it will bring more meaning to the variable's name.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp: `_ind` is short for indicator; at my first job it was the suggested appendage for boolean variables.

Comment: Fair enough. As I said, it's a personal thing - "indicator" is not the first thing that pops into my head :) Ultimately, consistency would be the most important factor, rather than the actual suffix or prefix used.