# SQL: Return Expressions from SQL CASE statement

Tags: sql, database, oracle10g, case

Thanks in Advance, i use an oracle 10g. In SQL case statement we pass the value and check the case according to value and return string. But instead of returning String, i want to return an expression. Is this is possible using oracle SQL query CASE statement for returning an expression? I do the following and oracle generate an error `ORA-00905:Missing Keyword`

```
SELECT ECL_CONTROL,
  CASE 
    WHEN ECL_CONTROL = 'N' THEN ('##0') = ('##0')
    WHEN ECL_CONTROL = 'Y' THEN (NVL(IL.ECL, 'X') = NVL(IM.ECL, 'X'))
  END
FROM ITEM_CONTROL WHERE ITEM_NO =  '2N2907A'
```

But The following run successfully :

```
SELECT ECL_CONTROL,
  CASE 
    WHEN ECL_CONTROL = 'N' THEN 'test'
    WHEN ECL_CONTROL = 'Y' THEN 'demo'
  END
FROM ITEM_CONTROL WHERE ITEM_NO =  '2N2907A'
```

I want to use this query as the inner query and return and expression for outer query. My query is following :

```
SELECT  LSM.ACTIVE_FLAG, LSM.ITEM_NO, IL.ECL, LSM.SERIAL_NO, IL.WAREHOUSE, IL.BIN, LSM.TOOL_STATUS_CODE,
LLG.NEXT_CAL_DATE, IM.PRODUCT_GROUP
FROM LS_SERIAL_MASTER LSM, LS_LIFE_LOG LLG, ITEM_LOCATION IL, ITEM_MASTER IM
WHERE   IL.PLANT = IM.PLANT AND IL.ITEM_NO = IM.ITEM_NO 
AND IM.PLANT = LSM.PLANT AND IM.ITEM_NO = LSM.ITEM_NO AND NVL(IM.PRODUCT_GROUP, 'X') =    NVL('PUMP', 'X')
AND LSM.PLANT = LLG.PLANT AND LSM.ITEM_NO = LLG.ITEM_NO AND LSM.SERIAL_NO = LLG.SERIAL_NO
AND LSM.LIFE_TRANS_ID = LLG.TRANS_ID AND LLG.SERIAL_NO = IL.SERIAL_NO
AND (SELECT ECL_CONTROL,
  CASE ECL_CONTROL
    WHEN ECL_CONTROL = 'N' THEN ('##0' = '##0')
    WHEN ECL_CONTROL = 'Y' THEN (NVL(IL.ECL, 'X') = NVL(IM.ECL, 'X'))
  END AS ECL_CONTROL_TXT
  FROM ITEM_CONTROL WHERE ITEM_NO =  '2N2907A')
AND LLG.MAINT_LMT_ID IN('T', 'U')
AND LLG.NEXT_CAL_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('02/1/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('02/11/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY').
```

My actual task is return an expression from inner query and used in outer query.

Comment: Reason being, `THEN` clause is for returning a value, not for comparing the values. You can't use any operators withe the values being returned in the `THEN` clause

Comment: No, it isn't possible. You're trying to return the expression as part of the result set which doesn't make sense; what would you do with the result? Do you actually want to return either `##0` or the value of `NVL(IL.ECL, 'X')`, which would be fine?

Comment: The ECL_CONTROL column contain flag value 'Y' or 'N', if the value is 'Y' i want to return `NVL(IL.ECL, 'X') = NVL(IM.ECL, 'X')` if the value is 'N' the return value is `('##0') = ('##0')` . This query is act as a inner query and in inner query these return statements return an expression for where condition.

Comment: `IL` and `IM` is the alias or outer query tables. if the flag is 'N' so ,we need only `true` expression in outer query `Y`, then i need to add another expression.

Answer (score 1):

No, what you've shown isn't possible. It doesn't make sense to have an expression in the `select` really. You can [have an expression *evaluated* instead of using a fixed string](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/expressions004.htm):

```
SELECT ECL_CONTROL,
  CASE 
    WHEN ECL_CONTROL = 'N' THEN '##0'
    WHEN ECL_CONTROL = 'Y' THEN NVL(IL.ECL, 'X')
  END
FROM ITEM_CONTROL WHERE ITEM_NO =  '2N2907A'
```

But you can't return the actual expression. In the code you've shown the first expression would always evaluate to `true` anyway (and booleans don't exist in plain SQL either), so I think this is maybe what you actually intended and you're confused about how to assign the expression value. You haven't shown where `IL` and `IM` come from so it's hard to tell quite what you want.

You can use a `case` directly in a `where` clause:

```
SELECT ...
FROM IM, IL, ITEM_CONTROL -- joined in some way
WHERE CASE 
    WHEN ECL_CONTROL = 'N' THEN '##0'
    WHEN ECL_CONTROL = 'Y' THEN NVL(IL.ECL, 'X')
  END = CASE 
    WHEN ECL_CONTROL = 'N' THEN '##0'
    WHEN ECL_CONTROL = 'Y' THEN NVL(IM.ECL, 'X')
  END
```

Though that might be clearer as:

```
WHERE ECL_CONTROL = 'N' OR NVL(IL.ECL, 'X') = NVL(IM.ECL, 'X')
```

From the larger query you added:

```
SELECT LSM.ACTIVE_FLAG, LSM.ITEM_NO, IL.ECL, LSM.SERIAL_NO, IL.WAREHOUSE,
  IL.BIN, LSM.TOOL_STATUS_CODE, LLG.NEXT_CAL_DATE, IM.PRODUCT_GROUP
FROM LS_SERIAL_MASTER LSM, LS_LIFE_LOG LLG, ITEM_LOCATION IL, ITEM_MASTER IM
WHERE IL.PLANT = IM.PLANT AND IL.ITEM_NO = IM.ITEM_NO 
AND IM.PLANT = LSM.PLANT AND IM.ITEM_NO = LSM.ITEM_NO
AND NVL(IM.PRODUCT_GROUP, 'X') = NVL('PUMP', 'X')
AND LSM.PLANT = LLG.PLANT AND LSM.ITEM_NO = LLG.ITEM_NO
AND LSM.SERIAL_NO = LLG.SERIAL_NO
AND LSM.LIFE_TRANS_ID = LLG.TRANS_ID AND LLG.SERIAL_NO = IL.SERIAL_NO
AND LLG.MAINT_LMT_ID IN('T', 'U')
AND LLG.NEXT_CAL_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('02/1/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
  AND TO_DATE('02/11/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
AND ((SELECT ECL_CONTROL FROM ITEM_CONTROL WHERE ITEM_NO = '2N2907A') = 'N'
  OR NVL(IL.ECL, 'X') = NVL(IM.ECL, 'X'))
```

... though since the subquery is looking for a single row - with a fixed `item_no` that has relation to the other columns with the same name you reference in other tables - you could just include that table in the main query.

Either way. this would be clearer with explicit joins, incidentally; rather outside the scope of the question, but taking on your comment that the `item_no` is actually related, something like:

```
SELECT LSM.ACTIVE_FLAG, LSM.ITEM_NO, IL.ECL, LSM.SERIAL_NO, IL.WAREHOUSE,
  IL.BIN, LSM.TOOL_STATUS_CODE, LLG.NEXT_CAL_DATE, IM.PRODUCT_GROUP
FROM LS_LIFE_LOG LLG
JOIN LS_SERIAL_MASTER LSM ON LSM.PLANT = LLG.PLANT
  AND LSM.ITEM_NO = LLG.ITEM_NO
  AND LSM.SERIAL_NO = LLG.SERIAL_NO
  AND LSM.LIFE_TRANS_ID = LLG.TRANS_ID
JOIN ITEM_CONTROL IC ON IC.ITEM_NO = LSM.ITEM_NO
JOIN ITEM_MASTER IM ON IM.PLANT = LSM.PLANT
  AND IM.ITEM_NO = IC.ITEM_NO
JOIN ITEM_LOCATION IL ON IL.PLANT = IM.PLANT
  AND IL.ITEM_NO = IM.ITEM_NO
  AND IL.SERIAL_NO = LLG.SERIAL_NO
  AND (IC.ECL_CONTROL = 'N' OR NVL(IL.ECL, 'X') = NVL(IM.ECL, 'X'))
WHERE LLG.MAINT_LMT_ID IN ('T', 'U')
AND LLG.NEXT_CAL_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('02/1/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
  AND TO_DATE('02/11/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
AND NVL(IM.PRODUCT_GROUP, 'X') = NVL('PUMP', 'X')
```

`NVL('PUMP', 'X')` doesn't make sense though - the `NVL()` is pointless around a fixed value. Maybe instead of `AND NVL(IM.PRODUCT_GROUP, 'X') = NVL('PUMP', 'X')` you mean `AND (IM.PRODUCT_GROUP IS NULL OR IM.PRODUCT_GROUP = 'PUMP')`?

Comment: sorry for the `IL` and `IM` confusing , actual these are the alias of outer query tables.

Comment: @HarmeetSingh - the answer to your question is simply 'no'; if you want help achieving your wider goal you'll need to provide more context in the question, showing how the expression would be used. Though I think what I've shown might point you in the right direction. `case` might not be the right tool here. But without the context of the rest of the query I'm guessing.

Comment: OK , @Alex Poole, i describe my question.

Comment: thanks for giving me the solution, but my `ITEM_NO` is not fixed and its comes from outer query and when we use `((SELECT ECL_CONTROL FROM ITEM_CONTROL WHERE ITEM_NO = '2N2907A') = 'N'
  OR NVL(IL.ECL, 'X') = NVL(IM.ECL, 'X'))` it contains both expression, . But i need only one expression depends on `Y` or `N` value in outer query because if the values is `N` there is no need for this expression. thanks again alex.

Comment: Hey @Alex thanks for this, But i want to confirm one think, in oracle 10g sql, the `OR` operator is Short Circuit ?

Comment: @HarmeetSingh - well, yes (although I can only see it explicitly stated [for PL/SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/fundamentals.htm#CIHGJBFD) but it doesn't affect the result here, and doesn't involve more work since the second expression doesn't involve any calculation. I suppose you're sometimes skipping the retrieval of `IM.ECL` but that would only make any difference at all if it was in a different data block to the other `IM` columns you're using.

Comment: @HarmeetSingh - actually... [no, it isn't guaranteed to for SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8900752/266304). The optimiser decides what to evaluate when. But it still doesn't make any practical difference in this case as there are no side-effects.