# Why doesn't Oracle throw an error here

Tags: sql, oracle, oracleexception

I'm looking at a script I didn't write here. and it looks something like this:

```
SELECT
...
AND (
       A.FIELD IN
       (
        ...
        ...
       )
       OR B.FIELD IN
       (
        ...
        ...
       ) 
    )
...
```

On it's own the script runs fine. No errors. But when I change it to:

```
SELECT
...
AND B.FIELD IN
       (
        ...
        ...
       ) 
...
```

Oracle throws an `ORA-01722: invalid number`. How come it doesn't throw it for the first query though?

**Updated**

A.FIELD is a number
B.FIELD is a VARCHAR2

The value is working against is a number. So I understand and agree with the error, but I wondered why it isn't thrown in the first query. But the second it is.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing any of the values in the `B.FIELD`'s `IN`.

Comment: I would assume the first statement isn't evaluating B.Field section because A.Field is true in the OR statement, although I'm not sure if SQL evaluates statements lazily.

Comment: @X.L.Ant I've updated my Q. I understand why the error occurs, but not why it doesn't occur in the first statement but does in the second? How does Oracle execute a query like this

Comment: @JGrice I wondered about this, but for my own interest and understanding thought I'd ask here

Comment: I guess @JGrice is right. Oracle doesn't guarantee short circuiting in SQL, but I can't think of any reason besides that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Oracle's docs:

> When evaluating a logical expression, PL/SQL uses short-circuit
>   evaluation. That is, PL/SQL stops evaluating the expression as soon as
>   the result can be determined. This lets you write expressions that
>   might otherwise cause an error.

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/fundamentals.htm#sthref481 for further explanation and examples.

They also have this separate documentation specifically mentioning that for `OR`: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/short-circuit-evaluation-in-plsql.php

Comment: I agree, but this is an SQL query, not PL/SQL.

Comment: [This fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a6611/3) reproduces the error. The short circuiting seems to work here, but I'm quite surprised this even works as the types are incompatible. Unless finding some official documentation about this particular case in SQL, I would not rely too much on this.

Comment: PL/SQL short-circuits, but [SQL may or may not - it depends...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8900752/266304).

Comment: @X.L.Ant Thanks, I just looked at the fiddle and replicated the error. I have not done a lot with Oracle really, so thought I should ask those who are far more experienced with it.

Comment: @X.L.Ant Oracle automatically converts types as necessary, so `varchar2` and `number` are not per se incompatible. (Of course you could expect that Oracle automatically checks all concerned `varchar2` literals if they can be converted, but apparently the special case of literals is not handled differently than other `varchar2` expressions)