# joining based on columns priority

Tags: oracle

I want to join 2 tables based on columns priority

ex. Suppose Table1 has six columns(Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6)
If i want to join Table 1 with table2 (Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col7), it should

otherwise

```
Select Table2.col7
where 
first check col1 , col2 and col3 if match found no need go check more 
second check col1 , col2  if match found no need go check more 
third check col1  if match found no need go check more 
last ignore all col1 , col2 and col3 
AND Table1.Col4=Table2.Col4
AND Table1.Col5=Table2.Col5
```

I may not be clear with my words, if any concern please shout

Comment: Use 'OR' instead of 'AND'. If match found the other conditions are not checked

Comment: (!!!) UPD: I'm wrong: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900631/does-oracle-use-short-circuit-evaluation

Answer (score 0):

```
Select t2.col7
  from Table1 t1 inner join Table2 t2
    on
  case 
    when t1.col1 = t2.col1 then 1
    when t1.col2 = t2.col2 then 1
    when t1.col3 = t2.col3 then 1
    when t1.Col4=t2.Col4
       and t1.Col5=t2.Col5 then 1
    else 0 end = 1
  ;
```

Comment: @user6498752 I edited the answer. tell if that's what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks Vercelli for your time, but i have one more issue here, selection should base on t1.col4 and t1.col5 values , what i mean is if i have t1.col4 values  as (A,B) and  t1.col5 (1,0), so we'll have 4 options for combination
(t1.col4, t1.col5) =(A,1),(A,0),(B,0),(B,1) for each combination, it goes for below checks

case 
    when t1.col1 = t2.col1 then 1
    when t1.col2 = t2.col2 then 1
    when t1.col3 = t2.col3 then 1
    else 0 end = 1


Hope, you'll help me soon for this also ...many thanks in advance

Comment: @vercelli: `CASE` expressions don't belong in the `WHERE` clause. Use simple `AND` and `OR` instead.

Comment: @vercelli: And the join syntax you are using was made redundand ages ago. Use explicit joins instead (`INNER JOIN`, `CROSS JOIN` etc.).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - Changed to inner join. I don't like CASE on WHERE but I'm not sure if they belong or not there. I just found it useful in this strange case.

Comment: You use `CASE` when you need to create an evaluation of a boolean expression; in `WHERE` and `ON` you don't need to create any; they already are such evaluations. Your `ON` clause translates to: `ON  t1.col1 = t2.col1 OR t1.col2 = t2.col2 OR t1.col3 = t2.col3 OR (t1.Col4 = t2.Col4 AND t1.Col5 = t2.Col5)`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot tell SQL to try to join on a certain condition first and in case it finds no match to go on searching. What you can do is join all allowed combinations (matches on col4 and col5 in your case) and then rank your matches (such that a match on col1 and col2 and col3 is considered best etc.). Then only keep the best matches:

```
select col7
from
(
  select 
    t1.*, 
    t2.*,
    row_number() over 
    (
      partition by t1.col4, t1.col5
      order by case 
        when t2.col1 = t1.col1 and t2.col2 = t1.col2 and t2.col3 = t1.col3 then 1
        when t2.col1 = t1.col1 and t2.col2 = t1.col2 then 2
        when t2.col1 = t1.col1 then 3
        else 4
    ) as rn
  from table1 t1
  join table2 t2 on t2.col4 = t1.col4 and t2.col5 = t1.col5
)
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks thanks Thorsten and Vercelli, I am trying to run below code, but throwing error
BTW, I have introduced one more table now.

Comment: select DISTINCT CU.ID cu_id,  'XXXX', to_char(RR.EFF_FROM,'DD-MON-YYYY') Active_Date, NVL(to_char(RR.EFF_TO,'DD-MON-YYYY'), '31-DEC-9999') Inactive_Date
from
(
  Select  RL.*, CU.*, RR.*,
    row_number() over 
    (
      partition by RR.Divi_Flag, RR.Brand_Type_Code
      order by case 
        when RR.Dept_Cd  = FLOOR(RL.Sub_Section/10000) and RR.Section  = FLOOR(MOD(RL.Sub_Section,10000)/100) and RR.SubSection = MOD(RL.Sub_Section,100) then 1
        when RR.Dept_Cd  = FLOOR(RL.Sub_Section/10000) and RR.Section  = FLOOR(MOD(RL.Sub_Section,10000)/100) then 2

Comment: when RR.Dept_Cd  = FLOOR(RL.Sub_Section/10000) then 3
        else 4
    ) as rn
  from TABLE1 RL ,
       TABLE2   CU , 
       TABLE3  RR 
  WHERE  RL.Code = CU.FK_Rl_Code
  AND  RL.Brand_Type_Code  = RR.Brand_Type_Code 
  and NVL(CU.Dividend_Flag, 'X')  = NVL(RR.Divi_Flag, 'X') 
  WHERE cu.skeletal_full_ind = 'F'
       AND cu.discontinued_date IS NULL
)
where rn = 1;

Comment: @user6498752 - That seems to me like a new question. Is the original question answered?

Comment: No, its an original one, but going by thorsten's suggestion. if you have any other approch pls let me know.

Comment: On a quick glance: `WHERE cu.skeletal_full_ind` should be `AND cu.skeletal_full_ind`. (Apart from that you should't use pre-1992 joins anymore. Use `FROM table1 rl JOIN table2 cu ON ...` instead. Or are you using an Oracle version older than 9i?)