# Why can't I compare an empty string?

Tags: oracle11g, string-comparison

This block

```
BEGIN
  IF 'foo' = '' THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('True');
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('False');
  END IF;
END;
```

prints "False", as one would expect. But if the comparison is replaced with `'foo' <> ''` or `'foo' != ''`, it still prints "False". Why would that be so? What is the proper way to check whether a string is empty?

Comment: Try checking against NULL instead.  More information here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7286239

Comment: Can you try `length('foo') > 0` ?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Well that answers that. Thanks