# Is there an Oracle Trim equivalent that works on VARCHAR fields made up exclusively of whitespace?

Tags: oracle, trim

```
SELECT 1 FROM dual where trim('X ') = 'X'
```

Gives 1.

```
SELECT 1 FROM dual where trim(' ') = ''
```

Gives no rows.

Is there an easy way to select all rows where `field` is whitespace short of regex?

Is there a way to "trick" TRIM into TRIMming `' '` and giving `''`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Oracle, [the empty string is NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203493/why-does-oracle-9i-treat-an-empty-string-as-null/).  So the conventional approach would be something like

```
SELECT 1 
  FROM dual 
 WHERE trim(' ') IS NULL
```

That will also, of course, return results where the column is `NULL`.  If you want cases where the column is non-NULL and is solely composed of spaces

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  with t as (
  2    select 1 id, ' ' str from dual union all
  3    select 2, null from dual union all
  4    select 3, 'a' from dual
  5  )
  6  select *
  7    from t
  8   where trim(str) is null
  9*    and str is not null
SQL> /

        ID S
---------- -
         1
```

Just to round out the answer, if you want to use a simple `regexp_like` as well

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  with t as (
  2    select 1 id, ' ' str from dual union all
  3    select 2, null from dual union all
  4    select 3, 'a ' from dual
  5  )
  6  select *
  7    from t
  8*  where regexp_like( str, '^[[:space:]]+$' )
SQL> /

        ID ST
---------- --
         1
```

Comment: This might not work as expected if the OP is trying to tell NULLs from BLANKs. Perhaps something like
    select count(*) from (
    select ' ' txt from dual
    union
    select '' from dual
    union
    select null from dual
    )
    where txt is not null and trim(txt) is null

Comment: @arch -- yep, you're on the money, combined with the secret sauce of "the empty string is NULL".  /sigh.  Would not have guessed that.  Thanks Justin & archimede.  Money.  Justin -- Great answer on the history of '' == NULL iff Oracle at that link too, **which implies** `WHERE trim(' ') IS NULL` might not always work for VARCHAR fields (but will for VARCHAR2).