# MySql: ORDER BY ASC, Nulls at the bottom

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

**NOTE** My values were actually **empty strings** not null.

I want to sort my table Album ASC with nulls at the end. Every stack overflow post i found didn't work on my database.

Following doesn't work:

- SELECT Album FROM songs ORDER BY isnull(Album,'1')
- SELECT Album FROM songs ORDER BY Album NULLS LAST
- SELECT Album FROM songs ORDER BY Album IS NULL
- SELECT Album FROM songs ORDER BY -Album DESC
- SELECT Album FROM songs ORDER BY ISNULL(Album), Album ASC
- SELECT Album FROM songs ORDER BY ISNULL(Album)
- SELECT Album FROM songs ORDER BY (CASE WHEN Album IS NULL then 1 ELSE 0 END),Album
- SELECT Album from songs ORDER BY ISNULL(Album),Album;
- SELECT Album FROM songs ORDER BY case when Album is null then 2 else 1 end, Album

Comment: Are these really null values ?

Comment: how can i check if they are null? is there a difference between this "" and null ?

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542065/is-better-use-an-empty-value-as-a-or-as-null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select album from songs ORDER BY CASE WHEN album IS NULL THEN 1 WHEN album= '' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END DESC, album ASC
```

**It will take care of empty string as well**

Comment: Are you sure the values are NULL, not empty string?  To sort empty strings last, specify "order by case when album = '' then 1 else 0 end, album

Comment: @DanGuzman-SQLServerMVP is there a difference between null and empty string ? how would i go through this if they were all empty ?

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 how will i sort it if my strings are empty and not null then ?

Comment: select album ORDER BY CASE WHEN album IS NULL THEN 1 WHEN album= '' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END DESC, album ASC, sorry try this

Comment: this command gives me no results at all, both of them , you sure you are typing this right guys ?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your output, I believe you are confusing null and the empty string.

```
Select case when album is null then 'NULL'
        when album = '' then 'string.empty'
        Else album end as Album
From song
Order by case when album is null then 2
        when album = '' then 1
        Else 0 end, album
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84541/3

Comment: @shiro, it had a typo, but that shouldn't result in no results, it should result in an error.  If you don't get any result you have other problems.

Comment: its because im running sql queries on my custom php made site that doesn't recognize errors

Answer (score 0):

Maybe consider a ORM for php? Doctrine or Propel, there are many flavors.
Still creating SQL by hand, why?

But your NULL problem is not solved with an ORM indeed.

Why not set a constraint on this column:

```
NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
```