# Oracle null check for string field

Tags: sql, oracle

In this below example why other than "NAME1" all giving null as result in oracle 11g.

If I mention space explicitly it takes space otherwise null only not empty string.Please help me to clarify this.

In NAME2 I specify the empty space but still it gives null.

```
select 
NVL(NAME,' ') AS NAME1,
NVL(NAME,'') AS NAME2,
NVL(NAME,NULL) AS NAME3,
NAME AS NAME4 
from employee
```

**OUTPUT :**

(space),null,null,null

Comment: You might like to get used to using Coalesce(), the ANSI version of Oracle's Nvl(). It's more flexible as it takes 2+ arguments, and features short-circuit evaluation so can be faster.

Comment: Related but not quite a dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203493/why-does-oracle-9i-treat-an-empty-string-as-null/203536#203536

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because in Oracle a ZERO length varchar is treated as NULL.

In your example

```
NVL(NAME, ' ') AS NAME1 will evaluate to either NAME or ' ' - empty string.
NVL(NAME, '') as NAME2 will evaluate to either NAME or a zero length string
```

Answer (score 3):

Because '' is equal with null in oracle. For example these two queries are same:

```
update  test set name=''  where id = 15
update  test set name=null   where id = 15
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that in Oracle an empty string is equivalent to `NULL`.

You can see that this is true by executing the followig query

```
SELECT 'x' FROM DUAL WHERE '' IS NULL
```

This should return a single row, meaning that the condition `'' IS NULL` is `true`.

Comment: *and AFAIK in SQL generally* That is **incorrect**. For instance, in SQL Server an empty string and a null string [are two different animals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17283978/sql-coalesce-with-empty-string)

Comment: @JanDoggen, you're right. I removed the generalisation. It's still valid for Oracle though.