# SQL Coalesce with empty string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following:

```
Select Coalesce(Other,Industry) Ind from registration
```

The thing is that `Other` can be an empty string or `NULL`.
How do I get `coalesce` to work such that if `Other` is an empty string, `Coalesce` still returns `Industry`?

Comment: How do *you* think that coalesce should behave, as it seems to be something other than the standard?

Answer (score 250, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression or `NULLIF`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(Other,''),Industry) Ind FROM registration
```

Answer (score 41):

try this

```
Select Coalesce(nullif(Other,''),Industry) Ind from registration
```

Comment: Bummer! Shafted on a high value correct answer because someone wrote the same thing 6 seconds faster.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use a short-cut knowing that `NULL <> ''` doesn't evaluate to `TRUE`...

```
CASE WHEN other <> '' THEN other ELSE industry END
```

The logic then works out as follows...

- `CASE WHEN 'fubar' <> '' THEN other ELSE industry END`
  => `CASE WHEN true THEN other ELSE industry END`
  => `other`
- `CASE WHEN '' <> '' THEN other ELSE industry END`
  => `CASE WHEN false THEN other ELSE industry END`
  => `industry`
- `CASE WHEN NULL <> '' THEN other ELSE industry END`
  => `CASE WHEN NULL THEN other ELSE industry END`
  => `industry`