# Mysql order by column when not empty then order by other column

Tags: php, mysql

I would like some help that has had me stumped for two days. I need to retrieve data from a database and order it by `column1` when it isn't empty and then the rest of the result by `column2`

```
column1      column2
1            11
2            12
3            13
             14
             15
             16
```

Required result

```
1,2,3,14,15,16
```

I've tried numerous approaches, my latest failed attempt being

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY COALESCE(column1, column2) DESC";
```

and

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY COALESCE(column1, column2) ASC";
```

My above SQL is returning NULL value column1 above column2

Comment: Are the empty columns empty as in empty string or null?

Comment: are you expecting one or two columns in the return?

Comment: I need all columns returned but ORDER accordingly. The value is NULL

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? Your second query does what you're asking to do in your written question (order by `col1` when it isn't empty and `col2` when `col1` is empty), but that's at odds with your expected results. In your sample data, are the `col1` values for the last three rows `NULL` or are they an empty string? Or spaces? Or can they be any/all of these?

Comment: would you need some rows returned twice if a value is set in column1 and column2 such as the first row being returned as the first and fourth, or only the first? Do you want `1,2,3,11,12,13,14,15,16` OR `1,2,3,14,15,16`?

Comment: You're correct i mean't `1,2,3,14,15,16`

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY COALESCE(NULLIF(Other,''), column2) DESC";
```

I saw it here: [SQL Coalesce with empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17283978/sql-coalesce-with-empty-string)

Answer (score 1):

`coalesce()` would only work if the "empty" values in column1 are actually `NULL`. Empty strings will not trigger a `coalesce()` operation.

Beyond that, your query will NOT work. You cannot do a `select *` with two columns and somehow magically get one single column in the result. For this you'll need a UNION query:

```
(SELECT column1 AS col FROM yourtable)

UNION ALL

(SELECT column2 AS col FROM yourtable)
ORDER BY col
```

Comment: Thanks, i need to select all columns and return them but ORDERED accordingly. This select statement will only return 2 columns wouldn't it?

Comment: this would only return one column.

Answer (score 1):

If you want 1 column, you could try a combination of `NULLIF` and `COALESCE`, that should account for both empty and null values

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(column1, ''), column2) AS COL
FROM table
```

[**<kbd>SQLFiddle Demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5ac6/3)

In case you actually want all of the numbers on a single result row, separated by commas, you can use `GROUP_CONCAT` along with the previous code:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(NULLIF(column1, ''), column2)) AS col
FROM table
```

[**<kbd>SQLFiddle Demo2</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5ac6/11)

Comment: Thanks but I need ALL columns selected but just ordered accordingly. This would select and retrieve only one or two columns. I have 20 columns in this table.

Answer (score 1):

Old question but this solution worked for me:

`$SQL = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY COALESCE(NULLIF(column1, ''), column2)";`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `CASE` like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN LENGTH(column1) IS >0 THEN column1 
ELSE column2 END 
ASC
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html