# SQL coalesce with empty string ,NULLIF is not usable in my system

Tags: sql, coalesce

Try to use coalesce in my query, for example I want the following query

```
COALESCE('', '','THIS')
```

give `'THIS'`, but it turns out to be  `''`

Found one solution [SQL Coalesce with empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17283978/sql-coalesce-with-empty-string), but my system  could not accept NULLIF.

Comment: What is "your system"?  What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Well `coalesce()` returns the first non-null value. Which is `''` in your example. An empty string `''`  is something different then `NULL`  - unless you are using Oracle which treats empty strings and `NULL` the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NULLIF()` is not a standard SQL function, so it won't work depending on the brand of RDBMS you use.

The equivalent in standard SQL would be:

```
COALESCE(CASE columnname WHEN '' THEN NULL ELSE columnname END, 'THIS')
```

Or you might as well do this:

```
CASE columnname WHEN '' THEN 'THIS' ELSE columnname END
```