# Is it possible to use a COALESCE function inside a SUM function?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to use COALESCE function at postgres in a query like this:

```
SELECT 
  id_school,
  SUM(COALESCE((student->'name'->>'age'), '0')::numeric)
FROM
  teachers
GROUP BY 1;
```

The problem is at line:
SUM(COALESCE((student->'name'->>'age'), '0')::numeric)

I tried to use COALESCE because I'm receiving some empty strings and the ERROR:  *invalid input syntax for type numeric: ""*

Shouldn't COALESCE solve this casting error? Can't I use COALESCE in a SUM function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't actually need the `coalesce()` function inside the sum, because `sum` will ignore NULL values anyway.

You error isn't caused by a NULL value, but by an empty string.

So you need to convert the empty string to a NULL value. This can be done using `nullif()` in Postgres

```
SELECT id_school,
       SUM(nullif(student->'name'->>'age'), '')::numeric)
FROM teachers
GROUP BY 1;
```

If you could also have strings with blanks in it the JSON value, you might want to consider `nullif(trim(student->'name'->>'age'), '')`

Answer (score 3):

`COALESCE` returns first non-null argument. Empty string is non-null. You are trying to cast `''` to numeric value.

You can use `NULLIF` to get null instead of empty string in `COALESCE`.
[SQL Coalesce with empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17283978/sql-coalesce-with-empty-string)