# Difference between updation with NULL and ''?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have used to two queries to update one column as NULL:

```
update table_name 
set col1 = NULL
where col2 = 'MUTHU';

update table_name 
set col1 = ''
where col2 = 'MUTHU';
```

But when i used to query with function NVL then i am getting the same result for both queries.

```
select nvl(col1, 'value') from table_name;
```

My question is: what is the 'difference' and 'use' between  NULL and '' ?

Comment: can you show the sequence of your query fired? and the output

Comment: Are you using Oracle or MySQL? That makes a **huge** difference.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name with respect to the query above, I don't think they would make any difference. but is there NVL function in Mysql??

Comment: Do you know what `NVL` does? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm

Comment: @chetan: it **would** make a huge difference as Oracle treats an empty string as `null`

Comment: @chetan - with Oracle's "an empty string in a `varchar` is the same as `NULL`", yes, it does.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i am using oracle.

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203493/why-does-oracle-9i-treat-an-empty-string-as-null

Answer (score -1):

One difference is that null usually propagates so if you concat null with another string :

```
create table t
(
  col1 varchar(10),
  col2 varchar(10),
  col3 varchar(10)
  );

insert into t values ( null, '', 'hello' ) ;

select 
 concat(col1 ,col3), 
 concat(col2 ,col3) 
from t

>> NULL, 'hello'
```

Answer (score -1):

`''` implies that the column has a value, which is an `empty string`

But `NULL` means `“a missing unknown value”`

so `NULL` cannot be compared with `=, <=` and so on

Comment: Why down votes??
if anything wrong, please specify

Comment: incorrect - in oracle, `''` is indistinguishable from `NULL`.