# Check NULL on a column and return result

Tags: sql, oracle, function

hey this is my requirment.

i need to check whether a column is null if so i need to return 'MISSING' else empty sting.

```
Column1(PrimaryKey)   COLUMN2  COLUMN3
P1                    ABC      DEF
P2                    NULL    KJL
P3                     NULL     NULL
```

te result should be

```
COLUMN1  RESULT
P1         '' 
P2        MISSINGCOLUMN2
P3        MISSINGCOLUMN3,COLUMN2
```

I tried using CONCAT ('MISSING', NVL(COLUMN2,'COLUMN2')) - its working if the value is NULL but in case of valid value it is retirning the valid value; because we cant pass 3 parameters to the NVL statement.

Comment: Do you realize that, in Oracle, the empty string is exactly the same as `NULL`?  Other databases treat the empty string as a valid non-NULL value, Oracle does not.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203493/why-does-oracle-9i-treat-an-empty-string-as-null/203536#203536  So do you want the `result` for `p1` to be `NULL`?

Comment: Yes. the reason is after loading this final table i will pull LENGTH(RESULT)> 1 and mark entry to  the Error Logging table

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like

```
select Column1,
   case 
      when Column2 is null and Column3 is null then 'MISSINGCOLUMN3,COLUMN2' 
      when Column2 is null then  'MISSINGCOLUMN2' 
      when Column3 is null then  'MISSINGCOLUMN3' 
      else ' '
   end
from ...
```

Comment: Thanks JJG
i tried this  DECODE(COLUMN1, NULL, 'missingCOLUMN1','') let me know if this also fine?

Answer (score 0):

```
select column1, CASE
WHEN
Column2 is null and column3 is not null
then
'MISSING COLUM2'
WHEN
Column3 is null and column2 is not null
 then
 'MISSING COLUM3'
 WHEN
Column3 is null and column2 is  null
then
  'MISSING COLUM3, column2'
WHEN
Column3 is not null and column2 is not null
 then
''''
end as result
from table
```

Comment: Thanks harshit, i tried this DECODE(COLUMN1, NULL, 'missingCOLUMN1','')

Comment: what about the other conditions??

Comment: DECODE(COLUMN1, NULL, 'missingCOLUMN1','') || DECODE(COLUMN2, NULL, 'missingCOLUMN2','')   i will use the same condition for all the columns

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT "COLUMN1",
    (case when "COLUMN2" is null or "COLUMN3" is null then 'MISSING' else '' end)
    ||
    (case when "COLUMN3" is null then 'COLUMN3' else '' end)
    ||
    (case when "COLUMN2" is null and "COLUMN3" is null then ',' else '' end)
    ||
    (case when "COLUMN2" is null then 'COLUMN2' else '' end) as RESULT
FROM ...
```