# How to return nothing in an Oracle procedure

Tags: oracle

I am an Oracle novice and just started to use it a few days ago.

I want to convert this procedure from SQL Server to Oracle. Essensially I want to call a procedure that returns nothing... therefore no change to my application.

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[LC_UNBOOKTRADE]
    @EXEID VARCHAR(50),

AS
SELECT ''

GO
```

Answer (score 2):

First, a procedure in Oracle does not and cannot return anything.  A function returns something.  A procedure can have an `out` parameter.

Second, unless you're using 12.1, procedures in Oracle can't implicitly return a cursor by executing a `select` statement like they can in SQL Server.  It would be much more common in Oracle to use a view for this sort of thing.

Third, in Oracle, the [empty string is NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203493/why-does-oracle-9i-treat-an-empty-string-as-null/203536#203536) so if you have code that expects a non-NULL empty string to be returned, you're going to have to change that.

Potentially, something like this would be the closest equivalent code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE lc_unbookTrade( 
    p_exeid IN VARCHAR2,
    p_rc   OUT SYS_REFCURSOR )
AS
BEGIN
  OPEN p_rc
   FOR SELECT null
         FROM dual;
END;
```

Depending on the code you're using to call your procedure, though, this may not be a transparent change.

Comment: Thank you this compliled fine but I want to be able to call the procedure and return a null value i.e. EXEC lc_unbookTrade (p_exeid);

Comment: @user3706392 - Justin's said you can't return anything from a procedure. Maybe if you add the code you're currently using to call your SQL Server procedure to the question, it will indicate whether there is a transparent Oracle equivalent. Otherwise you're asking for the impossible.

Comment: The procedure is the same as above but what I want is when you run Execute lc_unbookTrade (exeid). The result to be an empty string

Comment: @user3706392 - A procedure in Oracle cannot return anything.  A function can return anything.  A function, however, cannot return an empty string (at least if you consider the empty string to be distinct from NULL).  If you wanted to use the SQL*Plus `exec` command to call a function that returns `null`, however, you'd need to provide a variable in which to return the result.