# Why does LIKE '%' not match '' or NULL

Tags: sql, oracle, null, sql-like

Basically i have a set of fields that user can search by. so i write a query of the form:

```
SELECT *
  FROM my_addr_vw
 WHERE     fname LIKE :l_fname
  AND mname LIKE :l_mname
  AND lname LIKE :l_lname;
```

When user does not pass any value to any of the criteria, i assume a '%'.

What that does is, if a record had **NULL** or no value in say, mname - then the record drops off.... What is a good solution to this problem of *NULL matches nothing!!*

Comment: null equals nothing...null doesn't even equal null.   Use where field is null or like statement

Comment: `''` does match `'%'`. `NULL` can’t be matched against because it’s not a string. If appropriate, store an empty string instead of `NULL`. Otherwise, if appropriate, coerce `NULL` to an empty string in your query. Otherwise, if you want an empty query to match everything, maybe build your query dynamically and omit empty criteria.

Comment: @minitech No, Oracle treats `''` as `NULL`.  Yes, it's not correct.  It's still what it does.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203493/why-does-oracle-9i-treat-an-empty-string-as-null    http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/34257

Comment: @BaconBits: Oh. Thank you, I didn’t know that. Also, that’s sad.

Answer (score 6):

Almost any comparison to `NULL` produces an unknown (what I think of as a `NULL` result for the comparison).  This includes `like` -- for both the pattern and the string being compared.

The `where` clause allows rows through only when the comparison is TRUE.  So, both FALSE and unknown are filtered out.

That explains the `NULL` piece.  The `''` is a bit more abstruse because here Oracle is different from other databases and the standard.  Oracle treats `NULL` and the empty string as the same.  So, `''` is really just a synonym for `NULL` (using default Oracle settings).  So, you cannot match anything to the empty string, just like you cannot match anything to `NULL`.

Comment: +1 Nit-pick: technically a comparison results in one of `true`, `false`, or `unknown`. Operations like addition can result in `null`, for example `42 + null`, or `'Hi ' + null`. But the result of `1 = null` or `true and unknown` is `unknown`

Answer (score 1):

> What is a good solution to this problem of NULL matches nothing!!

The solution is to use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`.

```
SELECT *
FROM my_addr_vw
WHERE   (fname LIKE :l_fname OR fname IS NULL)
    AND (mname LIKE :l_mname OR mname IS NULL)
    AND (lname LIKE :l_lname OR lname IS NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return a record with a `null` value with the `is null` syntax:

```
 where (:l_mname = '%' and mname is null) or mname like :l_mname
```

Comment: Not true. This will pull up false matches where criteria had a not null value but record had a NULL - would still match it.

I had a form of (:l_mname is null or mname like :l_mname) but that is ending up inefficient.

Comment: Edited the answer to only return `null` rows when your parameter is `%`