# Replacing "(null)" with blank cell in SQL query result

Tags: sql, string, oracle, null, dbvisualizer

I believe what I'm asking here is possible, but I haven't find a way yet :

Some cells in the result of my SQL *SELECT-FROM-WHERE* query are blank, and in DbVisualizer, `(null)` is written inside. I'd like to display a blank cell instead.
I've already tried with *CASE-WHEN* and the *NVL* operator, but it won't let me replace it by a blank `''`, I'm forced to use some `' '` or `'message'`.

I know I could just delete these spaces or messages with Excel later, but I'd like to know if there is a way to do it directly with DbVisualizer, instead of this workaround.

---

**EDIT:** Here is what my request looks like :

```
SELECT *things*,
  CASE WHEN
     (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table d2 WHERE *join-condition* AND *other condition*) = 1
  THEN
     (*sub-select query*)
  ELSE
     ''
  END
  AS NAME,
  *other things*
  FROM table d1
  WHERE *something*
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: In tsql `null` and `''` are not same...... in Oracle I think `''` and `null` are same. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203493/why-does-oracle-9i-treat-an-empty-string-as-null)

Comment: Thats correct in Oracle, ''=null. @BusyAnt please specify the database - is it Oracle?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your query is the following **ELSE** part of the **CASE** expression:

> ```
>  ELSE
>      ''
> ```

In *Oracle*, an **empty string** is considered as **NULL** value. So, all you need to do is use *something* else instead of `''`.

For example, to use a **space** instead of **NULL**:

```
ELSE 
   ' '
```

**Update** The issue is the **DbVisualizer** tool. OP is on version `8.0.12`. Prior to version `9.2.8` it cannot show **NULL** as an empty string. However, as discussed in this [forum](http://www.dbvis.com/forum/thread.jspa?messageID=11943), it has been fixed in [DbVisualizer 9.2.8](http://www.dbvis.com/download/).

Comment: I've thought about that, but the thing is : I want to avoid using **space**, and really display a cell that contains nothing, for *.csv* exportation purposes

Comment: @BusyAnt Explain *nothing*.

Comment: Well, *blank*, *empty*, so that when I export it into Excel the cells are empty

Comment: Then you need to upgrade your client to `9.2.8` as you can modify the settings to show `NULL` as empty string.

Comment: I've got only `8.0.12 Free`, you're right, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 4):

Did you try *standard* SQL function [coalesce()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm), as below ?

```
SELECT COALESCE(columnName, '') AS ColumnName FROM tableName;
```

---

**Syntax:**

[image: COALESCE Syntax]

```
COALESCE (expr1, expr2)
```

is equivalent to:

```
CASE WHEN expr1 IS NOT NULL THEN expr1 ELSE expr2 END
```

Similarly,

```
COALESCE (expr1, expr2, ..., exprn), for n>=3
```

is equivalent to:

```
CASE WHEN expr1 IS NOT NULL THEN expr1 
   ELSE COALESCE (expr2, ..., exprn) END
```

Above examples are from [Database SQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm#SQLRF00617)

Comment: *coalesce* is like a big *CASE-WHEN*, isn't it? what I see I could do with it is `coalesce(NULL,'')` so that all the cells with `(null)` will become empty. Is that what you thought ? My query is a bit Special, I will edit my question to make it more clear

Comment: coalesce() is the not-null for standard SQL. If you want to make all cells with `null` as empty, then in your select query you will write `SELECT COALESCE(columnName, '') AS ColumnName FROM tableName;` where columnName is the cell with null values.

Comment: Thanks, that may be useful,but do you think I can directly apply it to my query ? (see edit)

Comment: @ShishirKumar Actually, the issue has nothing to do with the database, but with the DbVisualizer client tool.

Answer (score 1):

Standard SQL provides [COALESCE(expr1, expr2, ...)](http://www.faircom.com/doc/sqlref/#33405.htm) as suggested by @Shishir.

`COALESCE()` takes a variable amount of arguments and returns the first expression that is `NOT NULL`

MySQL also provides [IFNULL(expr1,expr2)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull), which returns `expr2` when `expr1` `IS NULL`

**Examples**

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(field1, ''),
    COALESCE(field1, field2, field3)
    IFNULL(field1, ''),
    IFNULL(field1, field2)
FROM table
```

Comment: Actually, the issue has nothing to do with the database, but with the DbVisualizer client tool.