# Getting "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected" in a Sybase-working query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have built the following query running fine on Sybase engines :

```
select *, 
(select COUNT(*) from myTable where column1 != '' and column2!=column3) as myField1,
(select COUNT(*) from myTable where column1 != '' and column2=column3) as myField2
from 
(select column1,column2,column3,column4,column5 
from myTable 
where column1 != '' and column2 != column3) as SUB_VIRTUAL_TABLE
```

However, running the same query on Oracle engines will raise the following exception:

```
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

Could please anyone help to fix this syntax? 
Thanks a lot. 
P.s.: tables and columns exist, the query is indeed running fine when the engine is Sybase.

The expected result would look like this:

```
column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 | column5 | myField 1 | myField2
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
A         B         C         D         E         12          15 
E         F         G         H         I         12          15          
...
```

Comment: Unrelated but: `column1 != ''` will not do what you think it will. In Oracle there is no such thing as an empty string. You need to change that to `column1 is not null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use the `as` keyword in Oracle to alias subqueries.  You just specify the alias.  And you probably need to alias the `*` in your `select`

```
select sub_virtual_table.*, 
       (select COUNT(*) 
          from myTable 
         where column1 != '' 
           and column2!=column3) as myField1,
       (select COUNT(*) 
          from myTable 
         where column1 != '' 
           and column2=column3) as myField2
  from (select column1,column2,column3,column4,column5 
          from myTable 
         where column1 != '' 
           and column2 != column3) SUB_VIRTUAL_TABLE
```

Since a `varchar2` column in Oracle can never be equal to nor unequal to the empty string, the four `column1` predicates aren't doing anything.  You probably want to either remove them or do the proper `IS NULL`/ `IS NOT NULL` checks.  See this discussion on [why Oracle treats the empty string as NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203493/why-does-oracle-9i-treat-an-empty-string-as-null/203536#203536).

Comment: Thank you Justin, for the IS NULL tip as well!

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle `''` is treated like `null` hence the condition `!= ''` can be written like `is not null`.

Try this:

```
select SUB_VIRTUAL_TABLE.*, 
(select COUNT(*) from myTable where column1 is not null and column2!=column3) as myField1,
(select COUNT(*) from myTable where column1 is not null and column2=column3) as myField2
from (
    select column1,column2,column3,column4,column5 
    from myTable 
    where column1 is not null and column2 != column3
) SUB_VIRTUAL_TABLE
```