# Joining a Temp Table to Actual Table

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I need to verify that each *order* has been acknowledged. The problem is that each order can have multiple codes. The query I had (utilizing a `CASE` statement) would check for blank fields or fields with the string "None" to verify the order has not been acknowledged. It would return the appropriate result, but *multiple* rows (once for each possible response) and I only need (1).

I'm attempting to create a temp table that will return the appropriate result and join (via an order unique ID) the two tables together hoping to correct the multiple row issue. Here is the code:

```
DROP TABLE staging_TABLE;

CREATE TEMP TABLE staging_TABLE(
ORDERID varchar(256) ,
CODE varchar(256) );
/*Keeping data types consistent with the real table*/

INSERT INTO staging_TABLE
SELECT ORDERID,
CASE CODE
  WHEN 'None' THEN 'No'
  WHEN '' THEN 'No'
  ELSE 'Yes'
END
FROM ORDERS
WHERE UTCDATE > SYSDATE - 10
AND CODE IS NOT NULL;

SELECT R.QUESTION,
R.ORDERNAME,
T.CODE
FROM ORDERS R
INNER JOIN staging_TABLE T
ON R.ORDERID= T.ORDERID
WHERE R.UTCDATE > SYSDATE - 10
AND R.CODE IS NOT NULL
AND R.CATEGORY IS NOT NULL
AND R.UTCDATE IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
         R.ORDER,
         T.CODE,
         R.ORDERNAME,
         R.CODE
ORDER BY 
R.ORDERNAME,
R.ORDER;
```

Am I doing this correctly? Or is this even the right approach?

Comment: There is no `''` in sql here: `WHEN ''` try `WHEN IS NULL` instead, I mean RDBMs doesn't store empty strings

Comment: @JorgeCampos, no. In *PostgreSQL* empty string and `NULL` are not the same, and it does store empty string.

Comment: What is supposed to happen if the same order has one row with 'Yes' and one row with 'No' (after your `CASE` statement)? Also, this question seems hardly related to temp tables at all ... BTW, your column cannot be named `ORDER` (without double quotes), that would be a syntax error, please clarify.

Comment: @MatheusOl Thanks for the info, I was taking oracle missleading `''` as `null` into consideration for all RDBMs, which of course is wrong! As discussed in this thread [Why does Oracle 9i treat an empty string as NULL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203493/why-does-oracle-9i-treat-an-empty-string-as-null#comment77936_203551) ! You are totally Right! :)

Comment: "RDBMs doesn't store empty strings" lucky I can't downvote a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I doing this correctly? Or is this even the right approach?

No. You don't need a temp table for this. Your query might look like this:

```
SELECT question, ordername
     , CASE WHEN code IN ('None', '') THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS code
FROM   orders
WHERE  utcdate > sysdate - 10
AND    code IS NOT NULL
AND    category IS NOT NULL
GROUP  BY question, ordername, 3, "order"
ORDER  BY ordername, "order";
```

- `ORDER` is a reserved word. It's not possible to use it as column name unless double quoted. There is something wrong there.
- `AND R.UTCDATE IS NOT NULL` is redundant. It can't be NULL anyway with `WHERE R.UTCDATE > SYSDATE - 10`
- **`3`**  in my `GROUP BY` clause is a positional reference to the CASE expression. Alternatively you can spell it out again:

```
....
GROUP  BY question, ordername
        , CASE WHEN code IN ('None', '') THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END
        , "order"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DISTINCT keyword as follows so you will not need a temp table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT QUESTION,
ORDERNAME,
CASE CODE
  WHEN 'None' THEN 'No'
  WHEN '' THEN 'No'
  ELSE 'Yes'
FROM ORDERS
WHERE UTCDATE > SYSDATE - 10
AND CODE IS NOT NULL
AND CATEGORY IS NOT NULL
AND UTCDATE IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 2,3;
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` is a valid alternative if all columns used are in the `SELECT` list. To order by a different column, you would either need to a construct with a subselect or you have to use `GROUP BY` instead, or `DISTINCT ON ()`.