# Filtering for empty string in SQLAlchemy + Oracle

Tags: python, oracle, postgresql, oracle11g, sqlalchemy

I have a weird problem with querying for strings using Oracle 11g backend for SQLAlchemy. First, class definition (for Oracle, for Postgres it is the same minus `Sequence`):

```
class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'item'
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    ...
    review = Column(Unicode(2000), index=True)
```

Basic querying works without a problem with Postgres backend:

```
In [1]: len(DBSession.query(Item).filter(Item.review != '').limit(100).all())
Out[1]: 100
```

However, with Oracle 11g:

```
In [31]: len(DBSession.query(Item).filter(Item.review != '').limit(100).all())
Out[31]: 0
```

Filtering by empty Unicode string does not work either in Oracle:

```
In [32]: len(DBSession.query(Item).filter(Item.review != u'').limit(100).all())
Out[32]: 0
```

Why something so basic does not work with Oracle? And how can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with SQLAlchemy. Oracle treats empty string == null.

See: [Oracle treats an empty string as null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203493/why-does-oracle-9i-treat-an-empty-string-as-null)