# Oracle operator <> not working in varchar2

Tags: oracle

I have created the table `TEST`, for use operator `<>` in database Oralce.
When you run the following command, I found it strange not return any records.

why not return any records? In SQL Server and Firebird database the command works.

#### SQL that is not Working

```
select * from TEST where Adress <> '';
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7e89f/2

```
create table TEST(
    ID int not null,
    Name varchar2(100) not null,
    Adress varchar2(100)  
);

alter table TEST add constraint TEST_pk primary key (ID);

insert into TEST values (1, 'Emily', null);
insert into TEST values (2, 'Michael', 'Test');
insert into TEST values (3, 'Daniel', 'Test');
insert into TEST values (4, 'Alexis', 'Test');
```

Comment: Have you tried using double quotes instead of single quotes?

Comment: @ApoorvKansal - Oracle uses double quotes around identifiers, not values; that would get a different error (ORA-01741).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oracle famously [treats an empty string as null](https://stackoverflow.com/q/203493/266304).

You are doing the same as:

```
select * from TEST where Adress <> null;
```

... and the result of anything compared with null [is undefined](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements005.htm#g194888).

You have to use null comparison operators:

```
select * from TEST where Adress is not null;
```

[Read more about Oracle's handling of nulls](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements005.htm#SQLRF30037).